# Is there any difference between "foo is None" and "foo == None"?

Tags: python

Is there any difference between:

```
if foo is None: pass
```

and

```
if foo == None: pass
```

The convention that I've seen in most Python code (and the code I myself write) is the former, but I recently came across code which uses the latter.  None is an instance (and the only instance, IIRC) of NoneType, so it shouldn't matter, right?  Are there any circumstances in which it might?

Answer (score 274, accepted):

`is` always returns `True` if it compares the same object instance, whereas `==` is ultimately determined by the `__eq__()` method.

i.e.

```
>>> class Foo:
        def __eq__(self, other):
            return True

>>> f = Foo()
>>> f == None
True
>>> f is None
False
```

Comment: You may want to add that None is a singleton so "None is None" is always True.

Comment: And you may want to add that the `is` operator cannot be customized (overloaded by a user-defined class).

Comment: @study The method `__eq__(self)` is a special builtin method that determines how `==` is handled when used on a Python object. Here we have overridden it so that when `==` is used on objects of type `Foo` it always returns true. There isn't an equivalent method for the `is` operator and so the behaviour of `is` cannot be changed in the same way.

Comment: Is it because the definition of the foo class does not have a constructor, i.e., the __init__ function?

Answer (score 51):

You may want to read this: [object identity and equivalence](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2001-November/094920.html).

The statement `is` is used for object identity, it checks if objects refer to the same instance (same address in memory).

And the `==` statement refers to equality (same value).

Comment: I just tried
`a=1;b=1;print(a is b) # True`. 

Any idea why `a is b` turn out to be true even if they seems to be 2 different object (different address in memory)?

Answer (score 28):

A word of caution:

```
if foo:
    # do something
```

Is **not** exactly the same as:

```
if foo is not None:
    # do something
```

The former is a boolean value test and can evaluate to false in different contexts. There are a number of things that represent false in a boolean value tests for example empty containers, boolean values. `None` also evaluates to false in this situation but other things do too.

Answer (score 13):

`(ob1 is ob2)` is equal to `(id(ob1) == id(ob2))`

Comment: ... but (ob is ob2) is a LOT faster. Timeit says "(a is b)" is 0.0365 usec per loop and "(id(a)==id(b))" is 0.153 usec per loop. 4.2x faster!

Comment: the `is` version needs no function call, and no python-interpreter attribute lookup at all; the interpreter can immediately answer if ob1 is, in fact, ob2.

Comment: No, it does not. `{} is {}` is false and `id({}) == id({})` can be (and **is** in CPython) true. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230

Answer (score 12):

The reason `foo is None` is the preferred way is that you might be handling an object that defines its own `__eq__`, and that defines the object to be equal to None. So, always use `foo is None` if you need to see if it is infact `None`.

Answer (score 10):

There is no difference because objects which are identical will of course be equal. However, [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) clearly states you should use `is`:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.

Answer (score 9):

`is` tests for identity, **not** equality. For your statement `foo is none`, Python simply compares the memory address of objects. It means you are asking the question "Do I have two names for the same object?"

`==` on the other hand tests for equality as determined by the `__eq__()` method. It doesn't cares about identity.

```
In [102]: x, y, z = 2, 2, 2.0

In [103]: id(x), id(y), id(z)
Out[103]: (38641984, 38641984, 48420880)

In [104]: x is y
Out[104]: True

In [105]: x == y
Out[105]: True

In [106]: x is z
Out[106]: False

In [107]: x == z
Out[107]: True
```

`None` is a singleton operator. So `None is None` is always true.

```
In [101]: None is None
Out[101]: True
```

Answer (score 5):

For None there shouldn't be a difference between equality (==) and identity (is). The NoneType probably returns identity for equality. Since None is the only instance you can make of NoneType (I think this is true), the two operations are the same. In the case of other types this is not always the case. For example:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3]
list2 = [1, 2, 3]
if list1==list2: print "Equal"
if list1 is list2: print "Same"
```

This would print "Equal" since lists have a comparison operation that is not the default returning of identity.

Answer (score 4):

@[Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none#26698):

> I recommend using something more along the lines of
>
> ```
> if foo:
>     #foo isn't None
> else:
>     #foo is None
> ```

I don't like using "if foo:" unless foo truly represents a boolean value (i.e. 0 or 1). If foo is a string or an object or something else, "if foo:" may work, but it looks like a lazy shortcut to me. If you're checking to see if x is None, say "if x is None:".

Comment: Checking for empty strings/lists with "if var" is the preferred way. Boolean conversion is well defined, and it is less code that even performs better. No reason to do "if len(mylist) == 0" for example.

Comment: Wrong. Suppose foo = "". Then `if foo` will return false and the comment `#foo is None` is wrong.

Comment: Note to downvoters - my answer is quoting an answer that has since been deleted and disagreeing with it. If you _don't_ like the code in my answer, you need to _upvote_. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Some more details:

1. The `is` clause actually checks if the two `object`s are at the same
   memory location or not. i.e whether they both point to the same
   memory location and have the same `id`.
2. As a  consequence of 1, `is` ensures whether, or not, the two lexically represented `object`s have identical attributes (attributes-of-attributes...) or not
3. Instantiation of primitive types like `bool`, `int`, `string`(with some exception), `NoneType` having a same value will always be in the same memory location.

E.g.

```
>>> int(1) is int(1)
True
>>> str("abcd") is str("abcd")
True
>>> bool(1) is bool(2)
True
>>> bool(0) is bool(0)
True
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool(1)
True
```

And since `NoneType` can only have one instance of itself in the python's "look-up" table therefore the former and the latter are more of a programming style of the developer who wrote the code(maybe for consistency) rather then having any subtle logical reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: Everyone reading this: DO NOT use `some_string is "bar"` to compare strings EVER. There is NOT A SINGLE ACCEPTABLE REASON to do so and it WILL BREAK when you don't expect it. The fact that it works often is simply because CPython knows it would be stupid to create two immutable objects that have the same content. But it can happen nonetheless.

Comment: @ThiefMaster does the answer have the tendency to be misconstrued? Though, upon reading it again *I* couldn't find it to be(with the mentioning of "some exceptions"). Your statement only holds for strings and not `int`, right?

Comment: Not really, but since you have that example in your answer I thought it'd be a good idea to warn users that it's a bad idea to actually use that. Maybe add something like "# cpython specific / not guaranteed" behind that line...

Answer (score 1):

John Machin's conclusion that `None` is a singleton is a conclusion bolstered by this code.

```
>>> x = None
>>> y = None
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
True
>>>
```

Since `None` is a singleton, `x == None` and `x is None` would have the same result.  However, in my aesthetical opinion, `x == None` is best.

Comment: I disagree with the opinion at the end of this answer.  When comparing with none explicitly, it's usually intended that the object in question is exactly the `None` object.  By comparison, one seldom sees None used in any other context except to be similar to `False` with other values being truthy.  In those cases it is more idiomatic to do something like `if x: pass`

Answer (score 0):

```
a is b # returns true if they a and b are true alias
a == b # returns true if they are true alias or they have values that are deemed equivalence 


a = [1,3,4]
b = a[:] #creating copy of list
a is b # if gives false
False
a == b # gives true
True
```