# Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?

Tags: python, reference, equality, semantics

My [Google-fu](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19967/what-does-google-fu-mean) has failed me.

In Python, are the following two tests for equality equivalent?

```
n = 5
# Test one.
if n == 5:
    print 'Yay!'

# Test two.
if n is 5:
    print 'Yay!'
```

Does this hold true for objects where you would be comparing instances (a `list` say)?

Okay, so this kind of answers my question:

```
L = []
L.append(1)
if L == [1]:
    print 'Yay!'
# Holds true, but...

if L is [1]:
    print 'Yay!'
# Doesn't.
```

So `==` tests value where `is` tests to see if they are the same object?

Answer (score 1155, accepted):

`is` will return `True` if two variables point to the same object (in memory), `==` if the objects referred to by the variables are equal.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> b = a
>>> b is a 
True
>>> b == a
True

# Make a new copy of list `a` via the slice operator, 
# and assign it to variable `b`
>>> b = a[:] 
>>> b is a
False
>>> b == a
True
```

In your case, the second test only works because Python caches small integer objects, which is an implementation detail. For larger integers, this does not work:

```
>>> 1000 is 10**3
False
>>> 1000 == 10**3
True
```

The same holds true for string literals:

```
>>> "a" is "a"
True
>>> "aa" is "a" * 2
True
>>> x = "a"
>>> "aa" is x * 2
False
>>> "aa" is intern(x*2)
True
```

Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none) as well.

Comment: I found that: `echo 'import sys;tt=sys.argv[1];print(tt is "foo", tt == "foo", id(tt)==id("foo"))'| python3 - foo`
output: `False True False`.

Comment: You lost me with the `b = a[:]` slice operator list copy part, so I've edited your answer to have a comment there. Looks like I just reached the threshold to not have to have my edits reviewed before they apply, so hopefully that's cool with you. Regardless, here's a useful reference for how to copy lists that I came across and had to reference to figure out what you were doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2612815/4561887

Comment: Another way to demonstrate the difference is by comparing objects of different types, which can, of course, never be the same object but still compare equal when using `==`. So `5.0` for example, is a floating point value, while `5` is an integer. But `5.0 == 5` will still return `True` because they represent the same value. In terms of performance and duck-typing, `is` is always tested by the interpreter by comparing the operand's memory adresses, while with `==` it is up to the object to decide if it defines itself as equal to something else.

Comment: `1000 is 10**3` evaluates to True in Python 3.7 since 10**3 is type `int`. But `1000 is 1e3` evaluates to False since 1e3 is type `float`.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Whether or not `1000 is 10**3` is true is implementation dependent, and depends on the compiler pre-evaluating the expression `10**3`. `x=10; 1000 is x**3` evaluates to `False`.

Comment: Just a side note. Python 3.8 and onwards return a SyntaxWarning when comparing literal like *1000 is 10\*\*3*: `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?`

Answer (score 403):

There is a simple rule of thumb to tell you when to use `==` or `is`.

- `==` is for *value equality*. Use it when you would like to know if two objects have the same value.
- `is` is for *reference equality*. Use it when you would like to know if two references refer to the same object.

In general, when you are comparing something to a simple type, you are usually checking for *value equality*, so you should use `==`. For example, the intention of your example is probably to check whether x has a value equal to 2 (`==`), not whether `x` is literally referring to the same object as 2.

---

Something else to note: because of the way the CPython reference implementation works, you'll get unexpected and inconsistent results if you mistakenly use `is` to compare for reference equality on integers:

```
>>> a = 500
>>> b = 500
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

That's pretty much what we expected: `a` and `b` have the same value, but are distinct entities. But what about this?

```
>>> c = 200
>>> d = 200
>>> c == d
True
>>> c is d
True
```

This is inconsistent with the earlier result. What's going on here? It turns out the reference implementation of Python caches integer objects in the range -5..256 as singleton instances for performance reasons. Here's an example demonstrating this:

```
>>> for i in range(250, 260): a = i; print "%i: %s" % (i, a is int(str(i)));
... 
250: True
251: True
252: True
253: True
254: True
255: True
256: True
257: False
258: False
259: False
```

This is another obvious reason not to use `is`: the behavior is left up to implementations when you're erroneously using it for value equality.

Comment: With regards to the first example of `a=500` and `b=500`, just wanted to point out that if you set `a` and `b` to an interger between [-5, 256], `a is b` actually returns `True`. More information here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/306313/7571052

Comment: @AsheKetchum, yes, note that I wrote "It turns out the reference implementation of Python caches integer objects in the range -5..256 as singleton instances for performance reasons."

Comment: Just like to add my two bits here. Use ```is``` if you want to check if its the same object (say you have a list of city and route objects each; you could compare the locations, or merely check if its the same city or not - so ```is``` is the stronger comparison here). Else if you're only concerned about primitives, usually ```==``` will suffice. This is more of a thumb rule that will get violated when the going gets tough

Answer (score 61):

> ### Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in Python?

Yes, they have a very important difference.

**`==`**: check for equality - the semantics are that equivalent objects (that aren't necessarily the same object) will test as equal. As the [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons):

> The operators <, >, ==, >=, <=, and != compare the values of two objects.

**`is`**: check for identity - the semantics are that the object (as held in memory) *is* the object. Again, the [documentation says](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#is-not):

> The operators `is` and `is not` test for object identity: `x is y` is true
>   if and only if `x` and `y` are the same object. Object identity is
>   determined using the `id()` function. `x is not y` yields the inverse
>   truth value.

Thus, the check for identity is the same as checking for the equality of the IDs of the objects. That is,

```
a is b
```

is the same as:

```
id(a) == id(b)
```

where `id` is the builtin function that returns an integer that "is guaranteed to be unique among simultaneously existing objects" (see `help(id)`) and where `a` and `b` are any arbitrary objects.

### Other Usage Directions

You should use these comparisons for their semantics. Use `is` to check identity and `==` to check equality.

So in general, we use `is` to check for identity. This is usually useful when we are checking for an object that should only exist once in memory, referred to as a "singleton" in the documentation.

Use cases for `is` include:

- `None`
- enum values (when using Enums from the enum module)
- usually modules
- usually class objects resulting from class definitions
- usually function objects resulting from function definitions
- anything else that should only exist once in memory (all singletons, generally)
- a specific object that you want by identity

Usual use cases for `==` include:

- numbers, including integers
- strings
- lists
- sets
- dictionaries
- custom mutable objects
- other builtin immutable objects, in most cases

The general use case, again, for `==`, is the object you want may not be the *same* object, instead it may be an *equivalent* one

#### PEP 8 directions

PEP 8, the official Python style guide for the standard library also mentions [two use-cases for `is`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations):

> Comparisons to singletons like `None` should always be done with `is` or
>   `is not`, never the equality operators.
>
> Also, beware of writing `if x` when you really mean `if x is not None` --
>   e.g. when testing whether a variable or argument that defaults to `None`
>   was set to some other value. The other value might have a type (such
>   as a container) that could be false in a boolean context!

### Inferring equality from identity

If `is` is true, equality can *usually* be inferred - logically, if an object is itself, then it should test as equivalent to itself.

In most cases this logic is true, but it relies on the implementation of the `__eq__` special method. As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#value-comparisons) say,

> The default behavior for equality comparison (`==` and `!=`) is based on
>   the identity of the objects. Hence, equality comparison of instances
>   with the same identity results in equality, and equality comparison of
>   instances with different identities results in inequality. A
>   motivation for this default behavior is the desire that all objects
>   should be reflexive (i.e. x is y implies x == y).

and in the interests of consistency, recommends:

> Equality comparison should be reflexive. In other words, identical
>   objects should compare equal:
>
> `x is y` implies `x == y`

We can see that this is the default behavior for custom objects:

```
>>> class Object(object): pass
>>> obj = Object()
>>> obj2 = Object()
>>> obj == obj, obj is obj
(True, True)
>>> obj == obj2, obj is obj2
(False, False)
```

The contrapositive is also usually true - if somethings test as not equal, you can usually infer that they are not the same object.

Since tests for equality can be customized, this inference does not always hold true for all types.

#### An exception

A notable exception is `nan` - it always tests as not equal to itself:

```
>>> nan = float('nan')
>>> nan
nan
>>> nan is nan
True
>>> nan == nan           # !!!!!
False
```

Checking for identity can be much a much quicker check than checking for equality (which might require recursively checking members).

But it cannot be substituted for equality where you may find more than one object as equivalent.

Note that comparing equality of lists and tuples will assume that identity of objects are equal (because this is a fast check). This can create contradictions if the logic is inconsistent - as it is for `nan`:

```
>>> [nan] == [nan]
True
>>> (nan,) == (nan,)
True
```

### A Cautionary Tale:

The question is attempting to use `is` to compare integers. You shouldn't assume that an instance of an integer is the same instance as one obtained by another reference. This story explains why.

A commenter had code that relied on the fact that small integers (-5 to 256 inclusive) are singletons in Python, instead of checking for equality.

> Wow, this can lead to some insidious bugs. I had some code that checked if a is b, which worked as I wanted because a and b are typically small numbers. The bug only happened today, after six months in production, because a and b were finally large enough to not be cached. – gwg

It worked in development. It may have passed some unittests.

And it worked in production - until the code checked for an integer larger than 256, at which point it failed in production.

This is a production failure that could have been caught in code review or possibly with a style-checker.

Let me emphasize: *[do not use `is` to compare integers.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28864111/541136)*

Comment: "do not use is at all" would be a good rule too. The idiomatic `is None` being an exception, but that said `== None` works too...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Another exception: The [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#comparisons) seems to recommend using `is` for comparing `Enum`s.

Comment: is that mean two custom classes compare, like a = Car("new"), B=Car("new"), if we use a==b, this is equal to a is b, am i right?

Comment: @UniSize I don't think you are right. Problems: 1. you say a, and B, but then you say a==b (lowercase) and Python is case-sensitive. 2. you don't say whether a and b are supposed to be equivalent, but two instantiations with the same arguments imply that they are equivalent, but not the same objects, thus you would be wrong in your interpretation. Please reread my answer here and let me know what's missing, and be careful and explicit in your response.

Comment: @AaronHall My appology, first of all, it's a typo. I revised it, a = Car("new"), b=Car("new"), if we use a==b, is this equal to a is b? 
I understand that "is" is checking whether two objects are in the same memory location, and a==b is the comparison between two objects. Based on the testing, a==b return false, and a is b return false as well. With the same initialization, why will a==b return false?

Comment: @UniSize That's why I said "think" - The default `__eq__` implementation uses `is`, in which case you would be right. Most custom implementations (and this should be done early in the lifecycle of the object definition, see my PyGotham talk on the subject: https://youtu.be/iGfggZqXmB0 ) will usually have two separate instantiations with the same arguments for instantiation test as equivalent - in which case you would be wrong. You still didn't say whether a and b are *supposed* to be equivalent. If you can't find a Q&A that covers this topic, I suggest you write a new question.

Comment: Worth mentioning that `a is b` is [not necessarily](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2319238/10133797) the same as `id(a) == id(b)`, or that `a` and `b` can't just be 'anything'. My understanding of `is` was based on this, and a reputable textbook made the same mistake.

Comment: As you explain, identity of referred instances ("`is`"), or *referent identity*, is the stricter (and strictest?) form of variable equality because it entails (or fully subsumes) *value equality* `==`, while the reverse isn't entailed. It may also be worth mentioning *type compatibility* here, a notion that yet further elaborates the spectrum of equality distinction. Most generally, it is also the case that *type equality* (either `type(a)==type(b)`, or `type(a) is type(b)` since type objects in python are singletons) is entailed by *referent equality*, and the reverse also not necessarily so.

Comment: Glenn, I think the big takeaway is that while in some cases the test for identity can substitute for a test for equality, and while in some cases this is desirable, in most cases this is undesirable, so we need to be careful to use the correct test for the situation. Additionally, the test for identity of types, while in some cases could be correct, doesn't support substitutability of subclasses for their parent classes.

Answer (score 48):

`==` determines if the values are equal, while `is` determines if they are the exact same object.

Answer (score 26):

## What's the difference between `is` and `==`?

`==` and `is` are different comparison! As others already said:

- `==` compares the values of the objects.
- `is` compares the references of the objects.

In Python names refer to objects, for example in this case `value1` and `value2` refer to an `int` instance storing the value `1000`:

```
value1 = 1000
value2 = value1
```

[image]

Because `value2` refers to the same object `is` and `==` will give `True`:

```
>>> value1 == value2
True
>>> value1 is value2
True
```

In the following example the names `value1` and `value2` refer to different `int` instances, even if both store the same integer:

```
>>> value1 = 1000
>>> value2 = 1000
```

[image]

Because the same value (integer) is stored `==` will be `True`, that's why it's often called "value comparison". However `is` will return `False` because these are different objects:

```
>>> value1 == value2
True
>>> value1 is value2
False
```

### When to use which?

Generally `is` is a much faster comparison. That's why CPython caches (or maybe *reuses* would be the better term) certain objects like small integers, some strings, etc. But this should be treated as *implementation detail* that could (even if unlikely) change at any point without warning.

You should **only use `is`** if you:

- want to check if two objects are really the same object (not just the same "value"). One example can be if *you* use a singleton object as constant.
- want to compare a value to a [Python *constant*](https://docs.python.org/library/constants.html). The constants in Python are:

  - `None`
  - `True`<sup>1</sup>
  - `False`<sup>1</sup>
  - `NotImplemented`
  - `Ellipsis`
  - `__debug__`
  - classes (for example `int is int` or `int is float`)
  - there could be additional constants in built-in modules or 3rd party modules. For example [`np.ma.masked`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.masked) from the NumPy module)

In **every other case you should use `==`** to check for equality.

### Can I customize the behavior?

There is some aspect to `==` that hasn't been mentioned already in the other answers: It's part of [Pythons "Data model"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#data-model). That means its behavior can be customized using the [`__eq__`](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method. For example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._value = val

    def __eq__(self, other):
        print('__eq__ method called')
        try:
            return self._value == other._value
        except AttributeError:
            raise TypeError('Cannot compare {0} to objects of type {1}'
                            .format(type(self), type(other)))
```

This is just an artificial example to illustrate that the method is really called:

```
>>> MyClass(10) == MyClass(10)
__eq__ method called
True
```

Note that by default (if no other implementation of `__eq__` can be found in the class or the superclasses) `__eq__` uses `is`:

```
class AClass(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

>>> a = AClass(10)
>>> b = AClass(10)
>>> a == b
False
>>> a == a
```

So it's actually important to implement `__eq__` if you want "more" than just reference-comparison for custom classes!

On the other hand you cannot customize `is` checks. It will always compare *just* if you have the same reference.

### Will these comparisons always return a boolean?

Because `__eq__` can be re-implemented or overridden, it's not limited to return `True` or `False`. It *could* return anything (but in most cases it should return a boolean!).

For example with NumPy arrays the `==` will return an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.arange(10) == 2
array([False, False,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

But `is` checks will always return `True` or `False`!

---

<sup>1</sup> As Aaron Hall mentioned in the comments:

Generally you shouldn't do any `is True` or `is False` checks because one normally uses these "checks" in a context that implicitly converts the *condition* to a boolean (for example in an `if` statement). So doing the `is True` comparison **and** the implicit boolean cast is doing more work than just doing the boolean cast - and you limit yourself to booleans (which isn't considered pythonic).

Like PEP8 mentions:

> Don't compare boolean values to `True` or `False` using `==`.
>
> ```
> Yes:   if greeting:
> No:    if greeting == True:
> Worse: if greeting is True:
> ```

Comment: I'm going to have to disagree on your assertion to compare "constants" with `is` - names that point to booleans should be checked with a boolean context - like `if __debug__:` or `if not __debug__:`. You should never do `if __debug__ is True:` or `if __debug__ == True:` - further, a constant is merely a constant semantic value, not a singleton, therefore checking with `is` in that case is not semantically correct. I challenge you to find a source to support your assertions - I do not think you will find one.

Comment: @AaronHall What makes you think that the constants aren't singletons? Note that only `None`, `True`, `False` and `__debug__` are what you would call "constant semantic value", because they cannot be reassigned. But all of them are singletons.

Comment: Read [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) - Ctrl-F and look for the word, "worse". - If you're unittesting, you'd use [self.assertTrue](https://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.TestCase.assertTrue)

Comment: @AaronHall In some circumstances you really need the `is True` or `if False` check (but yeah, these are pretty rare - but if you do them you *can* do them using `is`). That's why even CPython uses them sometimes (for example [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Lib/test/test_bool.py#L113-L115) or [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Lib/test/test_compare.py#L51-L53))

Comment: Why is `is True` worse than `== True`? Can `True is True` _ever_ fail? If anything `== True` is likelier to fail, as `__eq__` can be overridden to nonsense, but not `is`.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It's not about failing, it's just about style (this war copied from PEP8- the Python style guide). In the end you probably shouldn't need `== True` or `is True` ever (except for special cases or maybe in testing-code).

Comment: Disagreed with "never `is True`"; I've had a few cases where `is True` is clearly superior in simplicity and readability to its alternatives, and have seen it and `is False` used in major API production code. This sounds like the "don't `exec`" advice, which is valid but way inflated out of proportion ("never").

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Nothing in programming is without exception. It's also not inflated out of proportion... "Never use `exec` or `is True` "is the advise to protect readers (including more inexperienced programmers or casual passers-by) from themselves. It's generally assumed that people experienced enough with programming will know when to break the rules.

Answer (score 21):

They are **completely different**.  `is` checks for object identity, while `==` checks for equality (a notion that depends on the two operands' types).

It is only a lucky coincidence that "`is`" seems to work correctly with small integers (e.g. 5 == 4+1).  That is because [CPython optimizes the storage of integers in the range (-5 to 256) by making them singletons](https://docs.python.org/2/c-api/int.html#c.PyInt_FromLong). This behavior is totally implementation-dependent and not guaranteed to be preserved under all manner of minor transformative operations.

For example, Python 3.5 also makes short strings singletons, but slicing them disrupts this behavior:

```
>>> "foo" + "bar" == "foobar"
True
>>> "foo" + "bar" is "foobar"
True
>>> "foo"[:] + "bar" == "foobar"
True
>>> "foo"[:] + "bar" is "foobar"
False
```

Answer (score 12):

https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

`is` tests for identity
`==` tests for equality

Each (small) integer value is mapped to a single value, so every 3 is identical and equal. This is an implementation detail, not part of the language spec though

Answer (score 7):

Your answer is correct. The `is` operator compares the identity of two objects.  The `==` operator compares the values of two objects.

An object's identity never changes once it has been created; you may think of it as the object's address in memory.

You can control comparison behaviour of object values by defining a `__cmp__` method or a [rich comparison](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#basic-customization) method like `__eq__`.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at Stack Overflow question *[Python's “is” operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313)*.

What it mostly boils down to is that "`is`" checks to see if they are the same object, not just equal to each other (the numbers below 256 are a special case).

Answer (score 5):

As the other people in this post answer the question in details the difference between `==` and `is` for comparing Objects or variables, I would **emphasize** mainly the comparison between `is` and `==` **for strings** which can give different results and I would urge programmers to carefully use them.

For string comparison, make sure to use `==` instead of `is`:

```
str = 'hello'
if (str is 'hello'):
    print ('str is hello')
if (str == 'hello'):
    print ('str == hello')
```

Out:

```
str is hello
str == hello
```

**But** in the below example `==` and `is` will get different results:

```
str2 = 'hello sam'
    if (str2 is 'hello sam'):
        print ('str2 is hello sam')
    if (str2 == 'hello sam'):
        print ('str2 == hello sam')
```

Out:

```
str2 == hello sam
```

**Conclusion and Analysis:**

Use `is` carefully to compare between strings.
Since `is` for comparing objects and since in Python 3+ every variable such as string interpret as an object, let's see what happened in above paragraphs.

In python there is [`id`](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/id-function-python/#:%7E:text=id()%20is%20an%20inbuilt,the%20same%20id()%20value.) function that shows a unique constant of an object during its lifetime. This id is using in back-end of Python interpreter to compare two objects using `is` keyword.

```
str = 'hello'
id('hello')
> 140039832615152
id(str)
> 140039832615152
```

But

```
str2 = 'hello sam'
id('hello sam')
> 140039832615536
id(str2)
> 140039832615792
```

Comment: why does "is"" work like that for strings with spaces?

Comment: According to the previous answers:
It seems python performs caching on small integer and strings which means that it utilizes the same object reference for 'hello' string occurrences in this code snapshot, while it did not preform caching for 'hello sam' as it is relatively larger than 'hello' (i.e. it manages different references of 'hello sam' string, and that's why the 'is' operator returns false in later example)
Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @AkashGupta sorry for delay response.
I just added some more explanation why this thing happened in Python interpreter. I hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.9 and `str is 'hello'` throws `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?`  
This tells us that we need to use `==` for string comparison which is convenient.

Answer (score 5):

In a nutshell, `is` checks whether two references point to the same object or not.`==` checks whether two objects have the same value or not.

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=a        #a and b point to the same object
c=list(a)  #c points to different object 

if a==b:
    print('#')   #output:#
if a is b:
    print('##')  #output:## 
if a==c:
    print('###') #output:## 
if a is c:
    print('####') #no output as c and a point to different object
```

Answer (score 3):

As John Feminella said, most of the time you will use == and != because your objective is to  compare values. I'd just like to categorise what you would do the rest of the time:

There is one and only one instance of NoneType i.e. None is a singleton. Consequently `foo == None` and `foo is None` mean the same. However the `is` test is faster and the Pythonic convention is to use `foo is None`.

If you are doing some introspection or mucking about with garbage collection or checking whether your custom-built string interning gadget is working or suchlike, then you probably have a use-case for `foo` is `bar`.

True and False are also (now) singletons, but there is no use-case for `foo == True` and no use case for `foo is True`.

Comment: For `foo=1`, `foo==True` and `foo is True` are different.

Answer (score 3):

Most of them already answered to the point. Just as an additional note (based on my understanding and experimenting but not from a documented source), the statement

> == if the objects referred to by the variables are equal

from above answers should be read as

> == if the objects referred to by the variables are equal and objects belonging to the same type/class

. I arrived at this conclusion based on the below test:

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
tuple1 = (1,2,3,4)

print(list1)
print(tuple1)
print(id(list1))
print(id(tuple1))

print(list1 == tuple1)
print(list1 is tuple1)
```

Here the contents of the list and tuple are same but the type/class are different.