# What is the difference between "is None" and "== None"

Tags: python

I recently came across this syntax, I am unaware of the difference.

I would appreciate it if someone could tell me the difference.

Comment: See [Is there a difference between `==` and `is` in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python/134659#134659)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a difference between "==" and "is"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is)

Comment: It's unclear if this question is about `is` vs `==`, or about the nature of what exactly `None` is and how the behaviour differs in either context (the latter is why I ended up here).  Based on the vagueness and lack of OP responses... I'm surprised this has so many upvotes.  I mean... cmon... the question is not even written in the actual question...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any difference between "foo is None" and "foo == None"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none)

Answer (score 497, accepted):

The answer is explained [here](http://jaredgrubb.blogspot.com/2009/04/python-is-none-vs-none.html).

To quote:

> A class is free to implement
>   comparison any way it chooses, and it
>   can choose to make comparison against
>   None mean something (which actually
>   makes sense; if someone told you to
>   implement the None object from
>   scratch, how else would you get it to
>   compare True against itself?).

Practically-speaking, there is not much difference since custom comparison operators are rare.  But you should use `is None` as a general rule.

Comment: That was an interesting (and short) read. And some useful information into the `is` v. `==`.

Comment: Also, `is None` is a bit (~50%) faster than `== None` :)

Comment: @myusuf3: >>> timeit.Timer('None is None').timeit() |
0.225 |
>>> timeit.Timer('None == None').timeit() |
0.328

Comment: @myusuf3 You don't really need a proof for that. `is` is, basically, integer comparison while `==` is not only resolving references but comparing values which may have mismatching types.

Comment: Personally, I feel that `==` should be used in all cases except when either speed matters or you really need to know if you are referring to the same object.  `==` is much simpler and easier to understand.  It doesn't leave the reader wondering "why did he use `is` instead of `==`".

Comment: One on favour of "is". When a variable can be either None or something that has no meaningful comparison with None. For example, a variable can be a numpy.array or None (my particular case).

Comment: I would like to add to what @TimLudwinski is saying: first, if someone chose to override the equality operator to make None a special case, why would we want to tell them otherwise? Second, "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it." And the obvious way to check if something is equal to something is, well, the equality operator.

Comment: Personally, I find the == None and != None much easier to read than 'is None' and 'is not None' -- it's simply more concise. Imagine in Java, if you had to type in " is not null " in place of " != null" and " is null" in place of " == null"! I would imagine that would get very annoying, very quickly!

Comment: The truth is we all do it because of the SQL NULL trauma.

Comment: Numpy uses custom comparison operators and will perform element-wise comparisons for array == True/False, and at some point in the future will do the same for None. "If array == False:" does not work. In the future "if array == None:" won't work either. Custom operators cannot be ignored.

Comment: @Matt Thompson: For Numpy, using "if array is None" still works, though. "Is" checks whether the entire object is None instead of doing element-wise comparison.

Comment: I used to be a hardcore supporter of "use `is None` unless you have a good reason to do `== None`", but it was precisely the "what if someone wants to implement a `None`-like object" case which made me start wondering if actually maybe `== None` is The Right Way(tm)...

Comment: You know those hard-to-track-down errors when a line like `foo.bar` throws a `TypeError: NoneType has no attribute "bar"` and you're left having to step backwards through the logic and figure out where the `None` that ended up assigned to `foo` could have come from. I thought the other day that a magic `None` object which isn't a singleton but instead carries annotations about where it came from would help that, but that would break `is None` checks. Basically, when we say `is None`, we're marrying ourselves to the language implementation/design choice that `None` is a singleton.

Comment: @mtraceur Which None should always be singleton, to accomplish what you are referring to, the state could be stored and tracked externally- especially since this feature would be purely for testing, it would be best to prevent it from potentially any unwanted effects on the programs semantics, tho I do see why you would go about it that way. I've always felt that Python's use of None is inspired by Options, a concept from OCaml where either there is Something, or None. None being non-singleton means inherently that it is very well, Something. https://ocaml-lib.sourceforge.net/doc/Option.html

Comment: @Gamma2626 it is impossible to store the state you'd get from wrapping a None "externally", short of injecting extra code basically at every expression/bytecode which could assign/read/pass values around, while introspecting/recording the names of the variables/attributes/parameters involved. It's all well and good to say that None should be a singleton, but to the extent that it's true, it's also true that the vast majority of code shouldn't be using None, it should be using None-or-a-None-like-wrapper, and incidentally there's a equality operator for that.

Comment: @Gamma2626 to rephrase that in terms of types like Option (I agree, None is basically the "nothing" case of an option type) my point here is that the vast majority of code which currently uses `None` in Python (or Options in most code that has options) would actually be better designed if it used `DebugAnnotationMonad<Option<T>>` instead, where the `DebugAnnotationMonad` is a hypothetical mostly-transparent wrapper holding metadata that would be useful for debugging (which a language could even choose to optimize out, like how release builds can strip out assert statements in most languages).

Comment: @mtraceur Regardless, PEP 0008 does state how Python (regardless of Python implementation) expects None to be compared. That said, it is due to the fact that None is singleton, which as a design feature is a separate discussion.
[https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations)

Answer (score 232):

```
class Foo:
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return True
foo = Foo()

print(foo == None)
# True

print(foo is None)
# False
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26611/143931 for some interesting comments on this answer.

Answer (score 69):

In this case, they are the same. `None` is a singleton object (there only ever exists one `None`).

`is` checks to see if the object is the same object, while `==` just checks if they are equivalent.

For example:

```
p = [1]
q = [1]
p is q  # False because they are not the same actual object
p == q  # True because they are equivalent
```

But since there is only one `None`, they will always be the same, and `is` will return True.

```
p = None
q = None
p is q  # True because they are both pointing to the same "None"
```

Comment: This answer is not correct, as explained in Ben Hoffstein's answer below http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none/3257957#3257957. `x == None` may evaluate to `True` even if `x` is not `None` but an instance of some class with its own custom equality operator.

Answer (score 58):

It depends on what you are comparing to None. Some classes have custom comparison methods that treat `== None` differently from `is None`.

In particular the output of `a == None` **does not even have to be boolean !!** - a frequent cause of bugs.

For a specific example take a numpy array where the `==` comparison is implemented elementwise:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.zeros(3) # now a is array([0., 0., 0.])
a == None #compares elementwise, outputs array([False, False, False]), i.e. not boolean!!!
a is None #compares object to object, outputs False
```

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the current accepted answer, as it has easy to understand examples.

Answer (score 6):

If you use numpy,

```
if np.zeros(3) == None: pass
```

will give you an error when numpy does elementwise comparison.

Comment: Also: `np.array(None) is None` : `False`.