# python order of evaluation with ands in if statements

Tags: python, execution

It's common to put in a check for None or have similar error catch. Sometimes you also need another if statement that depends on x:

```
if x == None:
   if x[0]>0:
     ... # some code
```

Can you safely combine the if statements like this (for code brevity)?

```
if x != None and x[0]>0:
     ... # some code
```

Or does the interpreter not guarantee the order of evaluation and stopping after the first False?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is safe, because the operators [`and` and `or` short-circuits](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-operations-and-or-not).

**Note:**

- One  recommendation would be to use `is` if you want to check if an object is `None`:

  ```
  if x is not None and x[0] > 0:
      # ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because Python and is short-circuited ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)) and evaluated from left to right.

That means if `x == None`, it won't evaluate the rest: Python already knows that the evaluation of the full `and` is going to be `False`, because:
`False and True and True and True` is still `False`

Consider the following:

```
x = None    
if x is not None and a != "test":
    print "Point 1"
else:
    print "Point 2"
```

The variable `a` is not initialized anywhere, right? If Python hits that point, you'll get a `Name Error` exception, but what you get is:

```
Point 2
```

Meaning that Python doesn't even bother evaluating the `a != "test"` part.

Something similar happens with `or`. If any condition is `True`, Python stops evaluating:

The following code:

```
x = None
if x is None or a != "test":
    print "Point 1"
else:
    print "Point 2"
```

Doesn't throw an exception either, but outputs

```
Point 1
```

**Bonus**:

When checking if a variable is None, is much more recommended using `is` (or `is not`) rather than `==` or `!=` (as explained in the SO question [What is the difference between " is None " and " ==None "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none))