# Argument Presence Checking via Identity or Boolean Operation?

Tags: python

When checking a method's arguments to see whether they were set, is it pythonic to do an identity check:

```
def doThis(arg1, arg2=None):
  if arg2 is None:
    arg2 = myClass()
```

Or is it proper form to use a short-circuiting boolean:

```
def doThis(arg1, arg2=None):
    arg2 = arg2 or myClass()
```

In support of the former, [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) states:

> Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or 
>   is not , never the equality operators.    Also, beware of writing if x
>   when you really mean if x is not None --  e.g. when testing whether a
>   variable or argument that defaults to None  was set to some other
>   value. The other value might have a type (such  as a container) that
>   could be false in a boolean context!

On the other hand, from the [Google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn-history/r107/trunk/pyguide.html#True/False_evaluations):

> Use the "implicit" false if at all possible. ...

But at the same time states...

> Never use == or != to compare singletons like None. Use is or is not.

Does this apply to "None" since it evaluates to False always, and/or is a boolean comparison equivalent to ==/!= under the hood?

**edit**:
To answer the last question, "or" doesn't seem to be equivalent to "==" under the hood:

```
In [17]: timeit.timeit("1 or None", number=100000000)
Out[17]: 2.0310521125793457

In [18]: timeit.timeit("1 is None", number=100000000)
Out[18]: 2.618263006210327

In [19]: timeit.timeit("1 == None", number=100000000)
Out[19]: 4.554893970489502
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider what would happen if `arg2` equals a ["Falsish" value](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/truth.html) such as zero (or an empty string, list, tuple, dict or set -- to name just a few). Then

```
arg2 = arg2 or myClass()
```

would set `arg2` to `myClass()` even though `arg2=0` might have been the intended value for `arg2`. So [**always** use `is` to determine if `arg2` is None](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257919/190597).