# Input of 0 not working when converting to float?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm having a problem in the betting part of a blackjack game i am making, i would like the player to be able to bet $0 if they want to, however when you input 0 it simply repeats the input. Please help as this is the last step to a successful game that i have been working on for a while.

```
money=250
validbet=False
while validbet==False:
    bet = None
    while not bet:
        unchecked_bet = input("How much would you like to bet? $")
        try:
            bet = float(unchecked_bet)
        except ValueError:
            print("Sorry, that is not a valid bet. Please enter a valid bet.".format(unchecked_bet))

    bet=float(unchecked_bet)

    if bet>=0 and bet<=money:
        validbet=True
    else:
        print("Sorry, that is not a valid bet. Please enter a valid bet.")
        validbet=False


print("You have bet: $"+str(bet))
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 0. is a "falsey" value; try `while bet is None` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while not bet
```

evaluates to `False` if `bet == 0`. You probably want to check for

```
while bet is None
```

to handle `None` more explicitly.

Note that `bet == None` would work as well. But `bet is None` is more precise and the recommended way to check for `None`. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none) for more details.)