# Python: subprocess32 process.stdout.readline() waiting time

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

If I run the following function "run" with for example "ls -Rlah /" I get output immediately via the print statement as expected

```
import subprocess32 as subprocess
def run(command):
    process = subprocess.Popen(command,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    try:
        while process.poll() == None:
            print process.stdout.readline()
    finally:
        # Handle the scenario if the parent
        # process has terminated before this subprocess
        if process.poll():
            process.kill()
```

However if I use the python example program below it seems to be stuck on either process.poll() or process.stdout.readline() until the program has finished. I think it is stdout.readline() since if I increase the number of strings to output from 10 to 10000 (in the example program) or add in a sys.stdout.flush() just after every print, the print in the run function does get executed.

How can I make the output from a subprocess more real-timeish?

Note: I have just discovered that the python example program does not perform a sys.stdout.flush() when it outputs, is there a way for the caller of subprocess to enforce this somehow?

Example program which outputs 10 strings every 5 seconds.

```
#!/bin/env python
import time

if __name__ == "__main__":

    i = 0
    start = time.time()
    while True:
        if time.time() - start >= 5:
            for _ in range(10):
                print "hello world" + str(i)
            start = time.time()
            i += 1
        if i >= 3:
            break
```

Comment: I still get the same result even with using that. Note I am using subprocess32 with python 2.7.10

Comment: process = subprocess.Popen(command,
                               stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                               stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) with the following calls to read from the process:         while process.poll() == None:
            print process.stdout.readline() like in the example above.

Comment: ahhh :) instead of performing  print process.stdout.readline() I performed for line in iter( process.stdout.readline, b"") but still the readline did not return until the buffer was flushed.

Comment: Processes tend to buffer differently depending on whether stdout is a terminal or a pipe. You are using pipes, so the child will block buffer. Try using a pseudo terminal from the `pty` module or use `pexpect` which is built for this type of thing.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: related: [Python C program subprocess hangs at “for line in iter”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)

Comment: related: [Python: read streaming input from subprocess.communicate()](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: Could you mention the source where you get the code? I see 4 issues in the code (unrelated to your problem).

Comment: Its code which ive written myself :) could you please share?

Comment: 1. `command` should be a list on POSIX (e.g., `"ls -Rlah /".split()`) 2. Use `is None` instead of `== None` 3. `print line` doubles newlines, use `print line,` (note: comma) instead, to suppress the second unnecessary newline 4. `if p.poll(): p.kill()` is wrong. See [links in the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474554/python-subprocess32-process-stdout-readline-waiting-time/34474946#comment56697812_34474946)

Comment: thanks, why would you recommend using is None as opposed to == None?

Comment: okay found the information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should flush standard output in your script:

```
print "hello world" + str(i)
sys.stdout.flush()
```

When standard output is a terminal, stdout is line-buffered. But when it is not, stdout is block buffered and you need to flush it explicitly.

If you can't change the source of your script, you can use the `-u` option of Python (in the subprocess):

```
-u     Force stdin, stdout and stderr to be totally unbuffered.
```

Your command should be: `['python', '-u', 'script.py']`

In general, this kind of buffering happens in userspace. There are no generic ways to force an application to flush its buffers: some applications support command line options (like Python), others support signals, others do not support anything.

One solution might be to emulate a pseudo terminal, giving "hints" to the programs that they should operate in line-buffered mode. Still, this is not a solution that works in every case.

Comment: I didnt know that without a terminal it is block buffered, usefull info, thanks!

Comment: However what I am looking for is that is there a way to invoke a subprocess in non-block buffer mode?

Comment: thanks yes that works! but Andrea, is there a more generic way of doing this? i.e. if the process was not python then I would be stuck.

Comment: @Har: sorry, but unfortunately there are no ways, due to the nature of buffering

Comment: There was some documentation saying this:

bufsize will be supplied as the corresponding argument to the open() function when creating the stdin/stdout/stderr pipe file objects:

    0 means unbuffered (read and write are one system call and can return short)
but even with 0 it does not work.

Comment: @Har: that applies to the buffering done by Python in your parent process. It does (and cannot) affect subprocesses. The kind of buffering we are talking about is entirely done by the program itself or by the libraries it uses, the kernel has no role here (and therefore we cannot "transfer" a buffer size from a process to another)

Comment: Thanks I was not aware of that.

Comment: Littering flushes throughout your code is rarely the right answer and its not even possible on code that you don't control. Most programs should just write stdout and let the parent control whether its line or block buffered. Except on Windows where Microsoft has never provided a good pty solution.

Answer (score 3):

On most systems, command line programs line buffer or block buffer depending on whether `stdout` is a terminal or a pipe. On unixy systems, the parent process can create a pseudo-terminal to get terminal-like behavior even though the child isn't really run from a terminal. You can use the `pty` module to create a pseudo-terminal or use the `pexpect` module which eases access to interactive programs.

As mentioned in comments, using `poll` to read lines can result in lost data. One example is data left in the stdout pipe when the process terminates. Reading `pty` is a bit different than pipes and you'll find you need to catch an IOError when the child closes to get it all to work properly as in the example below.

```
try:
    import subprocess32 as subprocess
except ImportError:
    import subprocess
import pty
import sys
import os
import time
import errno

print("running %s" % sys.argv[1])

m,s = (os.fdopen(pipe) for pipe in pty.openpty())
process = subprocess.Popen([sys.argv[1]],
                           stdin=s,
                           stdout=s,
                           stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
s.close()

try:
    graceful = False
    while True:
        line = m.readline()
        print line.rstrip()
except IOError, e:
    if e.errno != errno.EIO:
        raise
    graceful = True
finally:
    # Handle the scenario if the parent
    # process has terminated before this subprocess
    m.close()
    if not graceful:
        process.kill()
    process.wait()
```

Comment: don't use `.poll()` ([it is unnecessary](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279) and you may lose data at the end). See [Python subprocess readlines() hangs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12419198/4279). Unrelated: if `process.poll()` is not `None`  then the process is dead already i.e., `process.kill()` should fail. Don't use `.poll() == None`, use `.poll() is None` instead if you need to compare with `None`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You are right! I kept with the original code as much as possible but after your comment I realized I'd better put up a more complete example. Thanks.

Comment: use `stdin=s` too, otherwise some programs may not enable interactive mode (and line-buffering). I don't like `time.sleep(.1)`, use `p.wait(0.1)` if you must (I don't see the point) instead. Magic number instead of `errno.EIO` is also not good. Also, your `os.fdopen()`-based code is not completely equivalent to [`os.read()`-based code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12471855/4279) (there are some issues).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I'm not sure why the code to specifically kill the child is in the original code.... I got the sense that this is some mid tier process that potentially terminates on a  signal from a parent process. If we are interrupted while reading the `pty` we need to kill the child before we wait. But if the pipe closed normally, we want to give the child time to exit. I'll slip in a fix.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian yeah, `readline` and simple iteration have a fair amount of code backing them. I've had the most luck with `readline`.

Comment: I've meant that `os.fdopen()` might not work correctly with file descriptors produced by `pty` i.e., in addition to EIO on EOF there could be other differences that might lead to loss of data or a deadlock on `.readline()`. Python 2 raises OSError, not IOError here. As long as you use `os.fdopen()`, you could use a `with`-statement here (to close the files).

Answer (score 2):

For things other than python you could try using [unbuffer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unbuffer):

> unbuffer disables the output buffering that occurs when program output is redirected from non-interactive programs. For example, suppose you are watching the output from a fifo by running it through od and then more.
>       od -c /tmp/fifo | more
>   You will not see anything until a full page of output has been produced.
>   You can disable this automatic buffering as follows:

```
unbuffer od -c /tmp/fifo | more
```

> Normally, unbuffer does not read from stdin. This simplifies use of unbuffer in some situations. To use unbuffer in a pipeline, use the -p flag. Example:
>   process1 | unbuffer -p process2 | process3

So in your case:

```
run(["unbuffer",cmd])
```

There are some caveats listed in the docs but it is another option.