# Sometimes None is printed - and sometimes it doesn't, can't get why?

Tags: python

I got this school assignment, here is my code:

```
class Doubly_linked_node():
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.value = val
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class Deque():
    def __init__(self):
        self.header = Doubly_linked_node(None)
        self.tailer = self.header
        self.length = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        string = str(self.header.value)
        index = self.header
        while not (index.next is None):
            string+=" " + str(index.next.value)
            index = index.next
        return string


    def head_insert(self, item):
        new = Doubly_linked_node(item)

        new.next=self.header
        self.header.prev=new

        self.header=new
        self.length+=1

        if self.tailer.value==None:
            self.tailer = self.header

    def tail_insert(self, item):
        new = Doubly_linked_node(item)

        new.prev=self.tailer
        self.tailer.next=new

        self.tailer=new
        self.length+=1

        if self.header.value==None:
            self.header = self.tailer
```

it builds a stack, allowing you to add and remove items from the head or tail (I didn't include all the code only the important stuff).

When I initiate an object, if I return `self.next` it prints `None`, but if I return `self.prev`, it prints nothing, just skips, I don't understand why since they are both defined exactly the same as you see, and if I insert only head several times for example `for i in range(1,5): D.head_insert(i)` and then I print `D` it prints `5 4 3 2 1 None` but if I do tail insert for example `for i in range(1,5): D.tail_insert(i)` and print `D` it prints `1 2 3 4 5"`as it should without the `None`. Why is that?

I have included an image:

[image]

Comment: as a rule of thumb, use "is None" instead of == None: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/is-none-vs-none

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve -- questions about code should contain the smallest possible amount of code needed to reproduce the same issue.

Comment: There is no `head` and `tail` method in the `Deque` class

Comment: Thank you for your fast response, I will mind it in future questions.
However i have tried both is and == and either way it prints None while it shouldn't.

Also note this is not the Deque python class its a made up class.

Comment: I have copied such a large segment of code because it is all imperative to the understanding of the problem in my eyes.

Comment: It would be a lot easier for you to debug this if you weren't defining `__repr__` in such a misleading way.

Comment: That is how we are asked to define the class in the home assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Keep in mind that you create a `Deque` which is not empty. You're initializing it with a Node with value `None`
2. You're interchanging the `value` and the Node object. When you're checking `if self.tailer.value==None:` it's probably not what you're meaning
3. Following to point 2 is a special handling for the empty Deque, where header and tailer is `None`

Here is what I have in mind, if I would implement the `Deque`. I'm slightly changed the return value of `__repr__`.

```
class Deque():
    def __init__(self):
        self.header = None
        self.tailer = None
        self.length = 0

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.header is None:
          return 'Deque<>'
        string = str(self.header.value)
        index = self.header.next
        while index!=None:
            string+=" " + str(index.value)
            index = index.next
        return 'Deque<'+string+'>'

    def head_insert(self, item):
        new = Doubly_linked_node(item)

        new.next=self.header
        if self.length==0:
          self.tailer=new
        else:
          self.header.prev=new

        self.header=new
        self.length+=1

    def tail_insert(self, item):
        new = Doubly_linked_node(item)

        new.prev=self.tailer
        if self.length==0:
          self.header=new
        else:
          self.tailer.next=new

        self.tailer=new
        self.length+=1
```

Comment: the `class Doubly_linked_node():` is given as part of the exercise that is why I must insert a certain value into it. how would you suggest i'd initiate  a `Deque` it if not by inserting a `None`?

Comment: Thank you Gunther that is a fine solution, by not initiating the `Deque` as a `Doubly_linked_node` and avoiding the node reference to the None; I'll point out that the reason I did not use the length for all the =='s is that it was a latter addition for another portion of the assignment (initially I only had header and tailer.)

Comment: I still think i'd stick to the `while not (str(index.next) == "None"):` because its quicker fix...(although a very ugly one)

Answer (score 1):

Following Günthers advice, I have modified the `__repr__` to this:

```
def __repr__(self):
    string = str(self.header.value)
    index = self.header
    while not (str(index.next) == "None"):
        string += (" " + str(index.next.value))
        index = index.next
    return string
```

that did solve the problem, but it is the ugliest solution I have ever seen.

does anyone know a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Following to the question of a better `__repr__` method here my proposal. Extend the `Deque` class with an `__iter__` method. So you can iterate over the `Deque` which is nice to have, e.g.:

```
for item in D:
  print item
```

Based on that the `__repr__` method is easy. Here is the whole change:

```
def __repr__(self):
  return 'Deque<'+' '.join([str(item.value) for item in self])+'>'

def __iter__(self):
  index=self.header
  while index is not None:
    yield index.value
    index=index.next
```

Comment: The functions as pre defined, i am not allowed to add any, just to fill em up with content.