# Return a string indicating what type of imbalance exists in a binary search tree

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

Having added a new node to an AVL. what kind of rotation do I need to fix it? I need to write a fuction that takes the binary tree and returns a string saying what type of imbalaced exist

```
class Node:
    """ A node in a BST. It may have left and right subtrees """

    def __init__(self, item, left=None, right=None):
        self.item = item
        self.left = left
        self.right = right


class BST:
    """ An implementation of a Binary Search Tree """

    def __init__(self, lst=None):
        self.root = None
        if lst != None:
            for x in lst:
                self.add(x)

    def recurse_add(self, ptr, item):
        if ptr == None:
            return Node(item)
        elif item < ptr.item:
            ptr.left = self.recurse_add(ptr.left, item)
        elif item > ptr.item:
            ptr.right = self.recurse_add(ptr.right, item)
        return ptr

    def add(self, item):
        """ Add this item to its correct position on the tree """
        self.root = self.recurse_add(self.root, item)

    def r_height(self, ptr):
        if ptr == None:
            return 0
        else:
            return 1 + max(self.r_height(ptr.left), self.r_height(ptr.right))

    def height(self):
        return self.r_height(self.root)
```

Comment: Small code review: replace `lst != None` by `lst is not None`, and `ptr == None` by `ptr is None`.

Comment: I might be wrong, but isn't this an [Unbalanced Binary Search Tree](http://opendatastructures.org/versions/edition-0.1d/ods-java/node37.html)? What do you mean by "type of imbalance"? Having more values on one side of the root than on the other?

Comment: def rotation(bst):
    node = bst.root
    if node == None:
        return 0
    else:
        leftH = bst.r_height(node.left)
        rightH = bst.r_height(node.right)
        if leftH - rightH > 1 or rightH - leftH > 1:
    return 1 + rotation(node.right) + rotation(node.left)

Comment: No its supposed to be an AVL but a new node is gonna be added making in imbalanced by 2 so I need to take that BST as an argument and return what type of imbalanced exists the method is supposed to find what type of rotation I have to do to fix it

Comment: Oh, you mean a tree [like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree), and you need to know if it's "left-heavy", "right-heavy" or "balanced" - then you must count the number of levels on each side, probably recursively, to get to your balance factor. The code you posted on your comment should be edited it into the main question for ease of reading (and proper tabbing). [Remember to ask if `something is None` insteand of comparing `something == None`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)

Comment: Yes thats it... I thinkx D