# Function to determine whether tree is a valid BST?

Tags: python, recursion, binary-search-tree

I have to determine whether given a list representing a tree, whether the tree is a valid BST (this question is taken from leetcode). I have seen other posts on this but I was wondering if someone could help me with my approach, since it is clearly not right. For example, for the tree [1,2,3] where 1 is the root, 2 is the left child, and 3 is the right child, my code returns true. Hopefully it only requires small changes, but it might be that the entire function's approach is incorrect.

Here is my code:

```
def isValidBST(self, root):
    if (root == None):
        return True
    if (root.left == None or root.left.val < root.val):
        return self.isValidBST(root.left)
    if (root.right == None or root.right.val > root.val):
        return self.isValidBST(root.right)
    return False
```

Secondly, I have seen approaches with a helper function that takes in a min/max value, but that confuses me. If anyone would also like to explain why that approach is a good/better one, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If `.. or root.left).val < root.val` is false, should you not immediately return `False`? (And the same - inverted - for `right`.)

Comment: I don't see where you have "a list representing a tree"

Comment: Use `is None` when comparing with `None` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none

Comment: And all those parentheses in your `if` statements are unnecessary.

Comment: @RadLexus: you have the answer; mind writing it up as one?

Comment: ... why all those useless parenthesis? `(root.left).val`?!? Ugh!

Comment: @JacobKrall: my Python-fu is not yet strong enough to cough up a ready solution. As you also have suggested a few further improvements, please go ahead.

Comment: @TavianBarnes the list is the input (so that would be passed in as root)

Comment: @Bakuriu got rid of some of the parentheses.

Comment: What do you think `[1,2,3].left` is?

Comment: I think you have to implement `min()` and `max()`.  Consider a tree: `root.val=2`, `root.left.val=1`, `root.left.right.val=3`, with all other nodes set to `None`. That invalid BST would pass your algorithm, wouldn't it?

Comment: @Robᵩ Thanks for pointing that out. I was just playing around with testcases and I realized that very issue. Do you mind posting a solution? The min/max approach is confusing for me so I would love to see either code or pseudocode with comments.

Comment: @Robᵩ: i love how you caught that, and the 3 answerers (including me) so far didn't :)

Comment: @JaneSully - my first attempt at using max() and min() would be exponentially slow, and I need to get back to my real job. I think the thing to do is to compute validity in a depth-first visit, and compute max and min values in the same visit, bubbling up as we go.

Comment: Your current approach is fundamentally wrong in at least one major way - if `root.left` is `None` or `root.left.val < root.val`, then you will never even look at the right sub-tree...

Answer (score 3):

I'd make a `min_max` method for `Node`s that finds the min and max values of the tree rooted at that `Node`.  Do sanity checking while finding those, and then `isValidBST` can just catch the exception

```
def max_min(self): 

    '''
    Returns maximum and minimum values of the keys of the tree rooted at self. 
    Throws an exception if the results are not correct for a BST
    '''

    l_max, l_min = self.left.max_min() if self.left else (self.val, self.val)
    if l_max > self.val:
        raise ValueError('Not a BST')
    r_max, r_min = self.right.max_min() if self.right else (self.val, self.val)
    if r_min < self.val:
        raise ValueError('Not a BST')
    return l_min, r_max

def isValidBST(self):
    try:
        if self.max_min():
            return True
    except ValueError:
            return False
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to implement the validity check:

```
class BST:

    def __init__(self, value, left=None, right=None):
        self.value = value
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

    def isValidBST(self):
        '''
        Simultaneously check for validity and set our own min and max values.
        '''
        self.min = self.max = self.value
        if self.left:
            if not self.left.isValidBST():
                return False
            if self.left.max >= self.value:
                return False
            self.min = self.left.min
        if self.right:
            if not self.right.isValidBST():
                return False
            if self.right.min < self.value:
                return False
            self.max = self.right.max
        return True

assert BST(2, BST(1), BST(3)).isValidBST()
case = BST(2, BST(1, None, BST(3)))
assert case.left.isValidBST()
assert not case.isValidBST()
```

Comment: Thank you so much!