# Increase the point of inviter after he/she has referred other

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

How can i increase the point of inviter when he has referred other to join. Point will be increase when refer is accepted. I could make the referral but could not increase the point when refer is accepted by the user to whom the refer was send by inviter.

Here is my code

```
class Invitation(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, verbose_name=_("e-mail Address"))
    invite_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    points = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=5)
    request_approved = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('request accepted'))

    def __str__(self):
        return "Invite: {0}".format(self.email)

class Referral(models.Model):
    referred_by = models.ForeignKey(Invitation, related_name="sharer", null=False, blank=False)
    referred_to = models.EmailField(unique=True, null=False, blank=False)
    refer_code = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, unique=True)
    refer_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)


def referInvitation(request, invite_code):
    try:
        # invite_id = request.session['invite_id']
        obj = Invitation.objects.get(invite_code=invite_code)
    except:
        obj = None
    form = ReferForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        referred_to = form.cleaned_data.get('referred_to')
        print ('referred_to', referred_to)
        if not obj == None:
            new_refer = Referral(referred_by=obj, referred_to=referred_to)
            new_refer.save()
            subject = "Request to Join Connyct"
            from_email=None
            message = "You have been invited by {0}".format(obj.email)
            to_email=[referred_to]
            send_mail(subject, message, from_email, to_email, fail_silently=True)
    context = {"form": form}
    return render(request, 'refer/refer.html', context)
```

Comment: Just FYI, instead of `if not obj == None:` do `if obj is not None:`

Comment: After the invitee accepts the referral then only the count should increase right?

Comment: yes only after the invite request is accepted, the count should increase.

Comment: Thanks @nik_m for sharing valuable information. Can i know the benefits of using is not over not obj == ?

Comment: FYI this is just python (not Django specific). [Here is why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)

Answer (score 0):

Send a accept/signup link along with the email message. After the user signup/accepted is complete then only increase count of the person who has referred, by doing the following:

`obj.points += 1`

Comment: Do i have to increase the points like you have said in middlewares? Because in my case when i refer you to join, you will get an email to join. When you click that link, a count has to be increased.

Comment: Design a link/url such that it can pass user objects. Like www.sample.com/register/<user_obj_refered>/. This link should eventually display a form to fetch the new user details and also increase the count simultaneously.