# AttributeError in Django 2 but not Django 1.11

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

The following code worked fine in Django 1.11, but in DJango 2 and up it fails:

```
'imageToLoad' : imageQ[0].imagePath
```

The error is `AttributeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'replace'`

imagePath is an ImageField.

I was reading through the DJango 2 documentation but couldn't figure out what the issue is.

Here is the entire code block:

```
def getContextFromObject(request,imageQ):
    if (imageQ != None):
        imageJson = serializers.serialize("json", imageQ)
        print("image id is " + str(imageQ[0].id))
        request.session['image_id'] = imageQ[0].id
        print("attempt to load: " + str(imageQ[0].imagePath))

        # Below is the block that fails on DJango 2. Specifically, it is the first part, 'imageToLoad' : imageQ[0].imagePath
        context = {'imageToLoad' : imageQ[0].imagePath,
                   'imageWidthPixels': imageQ[0].widthPixels,
                   'imageHeightPixels': imageQ[0].heightPixels,
                   'imageMeasuredCenter': (imageQ[0].swMeasuredCenter).quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN),
                   'micronsPerPixel': imageQ[0].micronsPerPixel,
                   'imageChannelSelect': imageQ[0].channelSelect,
                   'imageId' : str(imageQ[0].id),
                   'images' : imageJson
                  }
    else:
       context = { }

    return context;
```

Here is the full error traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 66, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\wsgi.py", line 146, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 81, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 95, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 37, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 87, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 35, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 128, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\vistagalaxy\images\views.py", line 717, in currentViewing
    return render(request, template, context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 36, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 175, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 155, in render
    return compiled_parent._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 167, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 67, in render
    result = block.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 943, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 910, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 106, in render
    url = self.url(context)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 103, in url
    return self.handle_simple(path)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\templatetags\static.py", line 118, in handle_simple
    return staticfiles_storage.url(path)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\files\storage.py", line 329, in url
    url = filepath_to_uri(name)
  File "C:\Users\abharadwaj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\encoding.py", line 252, in filepath_to_uri
    return quote(path.replace("\\", "/"), safe="/~!*()'")
AttributeError: 'ImageFieldFile' object has no attribute 'replace'
[14/Mar/2018 10:47:00] "GET /viewing HTTP/1.1" 500 59
```

Comment: Suggestion: you should us `if (imageQ is not None):` instead of `!=`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)

Comment: Please add the full error traceback!

Comment: @KlausD. I added the full error traceback.

Comment: What type is `imageQ[0].imagePath`? It seems like it's not the path to an image, but instead an `ImageFieldFile`. What path is `imagePath` supposed to contain?

Comment: @Blender it is an ImageField

Comment: @AashishBharadwaj: How are you using it in the template?

Comment: @Blender I am not entirely sure what you mean by template. Sorry for the late reply, I only work on certain days.
I have a folder called "templates", but these just contain HTML files.

Comment: @AashishBharadwaj: `context` is passed into a Django template, which contains something like `{{ imageToLoad }}` or `{% ... %}`.