# Python: same list in input but different outputs

Tags: python, list

I pass a list to a function and look at the output. When the list is hardcoded, I've got the expected output. But when I build the list from a string, and pass that list with the same content to the function, I don't have the expected output.

## First call:

```
tech = [ "Django", "Zend", "SQLite", "foo" ]

for tech_item in tech:
    print( test_main( tech_item ) )
```

## Second call:

```
raw_txt = "Django,Zend,SQLite,foo"
tech = raw_txt.split( "," )
# At this point if we print "tech" we have:
# [ "Django", "Zend", "SQLite", "foo" ]

for tech_item in tech:
    print( test_main( tech_item ) )
```

So, the input is/seems to be identical, but the output is different.

When I compare the content of the two lists (renaming the second list: tech2) I have:

```
print( tech[0], tech2[0] ) #Django Django
print( tech[0] == tech2[0] ) #True
print( type(tech[0]), type(tech2[0]) ) #<class 'str'> <class 'str'>
print( len(tech[0]), len(tech2[0]) ) #6 6
```

What am I missing?
Do you have any clue on how to find/resolve this?

## Edit:

Output I've got for the 1st case:

```
frameworks
frameworks
SQL
None
```

Output I've got for the 2nd case:

```
None
None
None
None
```

## test_main function

I give you the test_main function, but I'm afraid it is going to confuse you.
So, "looking_for" is the same each time. But "tmp" is different in both cases.

```
def test_main( looking_for ):
    global tmp
    tmp = None

    get_recursively( languages_tech, looking_for )

    return tmp
```

## get_recursively function

```
def get_recursively( data, looking_for, last_key="" ):
    if not isinstance( data, (list, dict) ):
        if data is looking_for: #item
            global tmp
            tmp = last_key
    else:
        if isinstance( data, dict ): #Dictionaries
            for key, value in data.items():
                get_recursively( value, looking_for, key )
        else:
            for item in data: #list
                get_recursively( item, looking_for, last_key )
```

## Languages_tech

```
languages = { "languages": [
"Ruby", "Python", "JavaScript", "ASP.NET", "Java", "C", "C++", "C#", "Swift", "PHP", "Visual Basic", "Bash" ] }

frameworks = { "frameworks" : [
"Django", "Flask", "React", "React Native", "Vue", "Ember", "Meteor", "AngularJS", "Express" , "Laravel", "Symfony", "Zend", "Ruby on Rails" ] }

databases = { "databases" : [
{ "SQL": ["MariaDB", "MySQL", "SQLite", "PostgreSQL", "Oracle", "MSSQL Server"] },
{ "NoSQL": ["Cassandra", "CouchDB", "MongoDB", "Neo4j", "OrientDB", "Redis", "Elasticsearch"] },
{ "ORM Framework": [ "SQLAlchemy", "Django ORM" ] } ] }

languages_tech = { "languages_tech": [ languages, frameworks, databases ]  }
```

Comment: `print( tech[0] is tech2[0] )` will always print `False` if `tech` and `tech2` are two different lists.

Comment: You usualy don't want to use `is` to compare strings. Strings that compare equal are not necessarily the same object.

Comment: In `get_recursively` you should compare strings with `==`, not with `is`: `if data == looking_for: #item`. This is explained here: [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce). (Could someone mark this question as a duplicate? I made a mistake by deleting the "possible duplicate" comment.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Short Answer

The following line in your `get_recursively()` function is erroneous

```
if data is looking_for:
```

Use this instead

```
if data == looking_for:
```

#### Long Answer

`a is b` will only evaluate to `true` if `a` and `b` have the same `id`. That is,

```
(a is b) == (id(a) == id(b))
```

By default, string literals are assigned the same id. For example,

```
>>> a = "Trebuchet"
>>> b = "Trebuchet"
>>> id(a), id(b)
(4416391792, 4416391792)
```

Note that both `id`'s are `4416391792`. This carries into `list`s as well (even though the lists aren't the same object and thus don't have the same `id`).

```
>>> a = ["Trebuchet", "Catapult", "Ballista"]
>>> b = ["Trebuchet", "Catapult", "Ballista"]
>>> id(a), id(b)
(4416392200, 4416861640)

>>> id(a[0]), id(b[0])          
(4416391792, 4416391792)
```

Note that `4416391792` is the exact same number from the previous example. This goes to show how strings point to the same object.

But when you bring in the `str.split()` function...

```
>>> a = "Trebuchet;Catapult;Ballista".split(';')
>>> b = ["Trebuchet", "Catapult", "Ballista"]
>>> id(a[0]), id(b[0])          
(4416392240, 4416391792)
```

`id(b[0])` remains at `4416391792`, we've seen that before. But now, note that `str.split()` creates a new string object with `id = 4416392240` in the list!!!

**This underlies the principle of why `data is looking_for` evaluates to false.**

Of course, `is` has its merits. For instance, we do `a is None` and not `a == None` ([*read more*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)). But it's important to discern when to use `is` and when to use `==`. When comparing literals for values such as strings, lists, or tuples, **use `==`**.

---

#### Further Reading:

[Why does comparing strings in Python using either '==' or 'is' sometimes produce a different result?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1504717/why-does-comparing-strings-in-python-using-either-or-is-sometimes-produce)

[Another example where variables can have congruent string literals but different `id`s.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1504740/10239789)