# "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'"

Tags: python, nonetype

I'm using def functions and when I run the code I get "TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'NoneType'". I get what the error is saying but is there any way to change the nontype into an int?

```
import random 
random.randint(1,3)

def P1():
   print("pick ")
   playerinput = int(input("rock(1), paper(2), scissors(3):"))

   if playerinput == 1:
        print("Player 1 chose: rock")
   elif playerinput == 2:
        print("Player 1 chose: paper")
   elif playerinput == 3:
        print("Player 1 chose: scissors")
   return (playerinput)

def P2():
    computer = random.randint(1,3)  
    if computer == 1:
        print("CPU chose: rock")
    elif computer == 2:
        print("CPU chose: paper")
    elif computer == 3:
        print("CPU 2 chose: scissors")

def winner():
    if P1()>P2():
        print("Player 1 wins")


def main():
   winner()

main()
```

Comment: You should abide by the rules for titles 'Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person'.

Comment: What is the purpose of the line after the import? What line do you get error at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if P1()>P2():` your error is occurring here

In Python, all functions implicitly return `None`, and return statements can be used to give a useful value

```
def f():
    pass
```

returns `None` when called

```
def f():
    return 1
```

returns `1` when called

Notice your function `P2` has no return statement, so calling it will result in `None`.
As stated by your error message, `>` (greater than operator, which you use with the result of `P2()`) is not supported between `int` and `NoneType`.  In general, `None` is not comparable besides `==`, but it is considered better to use `is` when determining if a value is `None`

[What is the difference between " is None " and " ==None "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You might have forgotten to return the value when you defined P2.

```
def P2():
computer = random.randint(1,3)  
if computer == 1:
    print("CPU chose: rock")
elif computer == 2:
    print("CPU chose: paper")
elif computer == 3:
    print("CPU 2 chose: scissors")
# Here we return the random value chosen
return computer
```

This way we are now returning an int instead of NoneType and therefore the comparison P1()>P2 should work.