# Python Big Query API Error - unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'

Tags: python, api

What I have done so far :

1. Individually printed out each parameter to see if values are printed. the `Output = nonetype`
2. printed the object row;  I see values but when I specifically print one of values(ex. `print("job id : {}".format(row.job_id)))`. output = nonetype
3. I printed the `Results` object the values are there but they are not printing

Here is my code below :

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

# Construct a BigQuery client object.
client = bigquery.Client()
# Set table_id to the ID of the destination table.
table_id = "my-project.my-dataset.my-table"
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig(destination=table_id)
job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'


def main(*args):
    query_job = client.query( """
    SELECT
    job_id ,
    creation_time,
    query, 
    total_bytes_processed 
    FROM region-us.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT 
    WHERE project_id ='my-project'
    AND creation_time BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 183 DAY)
    and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()
    ORDER BY creation_time DESC      
    """, job_config = job_config)
    results = query_job.result()  # Make an API request.

    print("Query results loaded to the table {}".format(table_id))
    for row in results:
        cost_dollars = (row.total_bytes_processed / 1024 ** 4) * 5
        print("The query data:")
        #print(f"JOB ID : {row.job_id}").format(row.job_id)
         print("JOB_ID = {0} |  Creation_TIME = {1} | QUERY = {2} | Total_Bytes_Processed = {3}| Estimated_Cost = {4}".format(row.job_id,row.creation_time,row.query,row.total_bytes_processed,cost_dollars))
```

This is the error message I am getting :

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

Any Ideas to why does the computer seem to think that either my row is a 'NoneType'?

Comment: Please provide the entire error message.

Comment: I have edited my question @AMC

Answer (score 0):

I replicated your code changing your project for one of mine and I had the same issue, so, I verified the query in the BigQuery Console, and I saw that some rows of column: 'total_bytes_processed' were Null.

Therefore, this line:

```
    cost_dollars = (row.total_bytes_processed / 1024 ** 4) * 5
```

Python return you the error:

`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'NoneType' and 'int'`

Because Python can't do this operation with None values.

Comment: Thank you for responding another method I have tried is to cast the row.total_bytes_processed as an int  but that has failed as well . Doesn't none values return 0?

Comment: For example if I wanted to try ```if row.total_bytes_processed == 'None' return 0 ``` would this not be possible for nonetypes?

Comment: Yes, is possible, also you can use  `is None` for the comparison instead of `== None`, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257957/12821865) for an explanation of the difference between these two options. A friendly note, in your line of code, you are using `'None'` (as string) instead of `None` (as object).