# What's the syntax for "If (function) returns None"?

Tags: python

I have a function called Lookup that runs some info through an API.  If the user's input is invalid and Lookup can't process it, it returns None.  How would I write something to the effect of:

```
if lookup returns none:
    return apology("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, figured it out (of course like a minute after posting this).  In case anyone else is curious because I couldn't find an answer:

```
if lookup(symbol) == None:
    return apology("invalid symbol")
```

Comment: should be carefule about if lookup, if not lookup, lookup is None, lookup == None

Comment: What's the danger there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none ... I've ran into some odd issues before, not saying you will but just saying be aware

Comment: Good to know!  Appreciate the tip

Comment: Never use `==` or `!=` to check if `None`. See PEP8 (https://pep8.org/#programming-recommendations and https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations): *Comparisons to singletons like None should always be done with is or is not, never the equality operators.*

Answer (score 2):

there are various ways you could achieve this.

```
if not lookup():
    return apology("invalid input")

if lookup() is None:
    return apology("invalid input")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if not lookup():
    return apology("invalid")
```

This should solve the problem.