# List[Optional[int]] type checking when assigning

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting, typing, mypy

`mypy` seems smart enough to detect that after checking an optional value for `None` the `Optional` part of the type is disregarded.

Meaning: declaring value: `Optional[int]` would result in value behaving like an `int` after `if value is not None`.

I think I am stuck on a similar issue but with `Optional int` in a `list`.

Here is the **demo snippet**:

```
a: List[Optional[int]] = [None, None]

a[0] = 5
a[1] = 10

b: int = 0

if a[0] != None:
    b = a[0]
```

It shows an **Error**:

```
test.py:12: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has 
type "Optional[int]", variable has type "int")
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

I do check if `a[0] is not None` but I don't know why it still fails to narrow down the type of a[0] from `int | None` to `int` as the condition for `None` is already checked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `mypy` currently understands `is None` and `is not None` checks:

https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8000

> You need to do `if self.ignore is None` for `mypy` to pick up that [...]

so apparently

```
if a[0] is not None:
```

should work. Note that `is not None` and `!= None` [may not mean the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none) anyway.