# If condition statement passes with wrong conditions in python

Tags: python

I am trying to check first_item.rulename value is empty or null or starts with 'OptumFormulary' using below code

```
if (first_item.rulename != '' or first_item.rulename == None or first_item.rulename.startswith('OptumFormulary')):
       ruledefinitions_rules = ruledefinitions_rules[1:]
 else:
       ruledefinitions_rules = ruledefinitions_rules
```

My first_item.rulename value is '802' but still it is getting inside the if loop condition.
[image]

In the snapshot, first_item.rulename is '802' on hovering.

Comment: `first_item.rulename != ''` and it goes in the if

Comment: My bad. Sorry, didnt notice it.

Comment: Just a comment, but you might also want to adopt the habit of comparing with `None` using the `is` operator rather than `==` as explained for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none/3257957#3257957