# None output after recurse through linked list

Tags: python

`currentNode` is a linked list I created, the nodes are 1, 2, 3.

```
def transformRecursive(lst):
    if lst == None:
        return
    else:
        return [lst.value].append(transformRecursive(lst.nextNode))

print(transformRecursive(currentNode))
```

The output only gives me `None` Instead of `["1","2","3"]`.

Comment: `append()` returns None in python. You are appending to the list, but you're not returning the list. You might try: `return [lst.value] + transformRecursive(lst.nextNode)`

Comment: [lst.value] + transformRecursive(lst.nextNode) would report builtins.TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "NoneType") to list. I think there is something wrong with my base case

Comment: There are some basics it seems @TianyuWang needs some info on, I tried to provide an answer that helps explain a few basics in addition to providing a working solution. However, it would help to know exactly what `lst` is --> a list? node? linked list? etc.

Comment: @TianyuWang, perhaps your base case should be an empty list. That would make sense to me as the analog of an empty linked-list.

Comment: You should try print(lst) after the first if and also print lst after the Else (before returning) to help yourself debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Some quick explanations:

For your `transformRecursive` function, what it appears you're trying to do is generate a single `list` of all linked "node" values. From what you have in `transformRecursive`, even if this behaved as you expected you would actually end up with something like `["1", ["2",["3"]]]` instead of `["1","2","3"]`.

From the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), when you use `append` on a list, it is equivalent to `myList[len(myList):] = [x]` (where `myList` is the list in question, and `x` is the item to be appended). Given the above explanation, what I think you actually might want to use here is `extend(x)` (which has the same behavior, e.g. it returns `None`).

Secondly, as @Mark mentioned, `list.append(x)` returns `None`. So you can't use this as an assignment or return value. It is meant to be called "in place" to change the given list. Example:

```
# Example 1
myList = [1].append([2])
print(f"Example 1: {myList}")

# Example 2
myList = [1]
myList.append([2])
print(f"Example 2: {myList}")

# Example 3
myList = [1]
myList.append(2)
print(f"Example 3: {myList}")
```

Output:

```
Example 1: None
Example 2: [1, [2]]
Example 3: [1, 2]
```

#### Mutability:

I'm a little fuzzy on what `lst` actually is in your `transformRecursive` function, but I've mocked up a simple `Node` class to mimic what I *think* might be close enough for demonstration:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value = None):
        self.value = value
        self.nextNode = None
```

Given this setup, an important demonstration is mutability, particularly when it comes to our custom class and passing an object as a parameter (and please note, this also applies to a `list` such as `[1,2,3]` as well).

```
def mutable_test(node):
    node.value = "Value was changed"

currentNode = Node("1")
print(currenNode.value)
mutable_test(currentNode)
print(currentNode.value)
```

Output:

```
1
Value was changed
```

This really highlights the importance of understanding how passing an object as a parameter to a function affects it. Even though I didn't return any value, or store it from a function call, my `currentNode` was still changed by `mutabile_test`. See below link for the related discussion that goes into a lot of detail on this.

#### Solution:

Given the explanation above, we can see where we might have some issues with your code, assuming otherwise it worked "as intended". With your function above, the intent does not seem to be to *change* the argument passed in, but rather create a list to return, which can be referenced and manipulated separate from the original `Node`.

We can use the following to do so:

```
def transformRecursive(node):
    # note the use of `is None` here
    if node is None:
        # return an empty list, see below reason
        return []
    else:
        # first we create the list in place
        result = [node.value]
        # we can then extend the result recursively, because if
        # we get an empty list, it simply won't be extended
        result.extend(transformRecursive(node.nextNode))
        # finally, return the extended result
        return result
```

Testing it out:

```
currentNode = Node("1")
currentNode.nextNode = Node("2")
currentNode.nextNode.nextNode = Node("3")

print(transformRecursive(currentNode))
```

Output:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

#### Follow on topics for consideration:

You may want to see some related discussions:

- [How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/986006/15744261)
- [What is the difference between "is None" and "== None"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257919/15744261)