# Cannot `find_all` when extracting elements from webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the honour awards from every player in the premier league table, however when I try to run this in a loop over many html links I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

I have found that this may be related the link not have the proposed elements I am searching for - However after printing the variable storing this information:

```
#example
None
None
None
None
<table class="honoursAwards">
<tbody>
<tr>
<th>Premier League Champion</th>
<th class="u-text-right">1</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="3">
<table class="playerSidebarNested">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>2019/20</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

I a guessing that the `None` values trip the collection from occurring?

Here's what I have done:

```
base = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/{}/'
link = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players'
payload = {
    'pageSize': '30',
    'compSeasons': '418',
    'altIds': 'true',
    'page': 0,
    'type': 'player',
    'id': '-1',
    'compSeasonId': '418'
}

football_pages = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['referer'] = 'https://www.premierleague.com/'
    s.headers['origin'] = 'https://www.premierleague.com'


    while True:
        res = s.get(link,params=payload)
        if not res.json()['content']:break
        for item in res.json()['content']:
           football_pages.append(base.format(int(item['id'])))
        
        payload['page']+=1


for urls in football_pages:
    pages = requests.get(urls)
    soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'lxml')
    table = soup_2.find('table', {'class': 'honoursAwards'})
    tables=[item.text for item in table.find_all('th')] #error is here
    print(tables)
```

Comment: What happened when you tried manually visiting each of the web pages specified in `football_pages`, and verifying that all of them have a `<table class="honoursAwards">` element? What do you expect to happen if you try to `.find_all` from this table if it doesn't exist on the page? What happened when you tried verifying the list of URLs that you get in `football_pages`, itself?

Comment: "I a guessing that the None values trip the collection from occurring?" What happened when you tried to write code based on this assumption? For example, did you consider writing code that checks `if` the value in question `is None`, and doing something different in that case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not every player will have an awards table. You can simply use a try/except.

I'd also just use pandas to parse the table:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd

base = 'https://www.premierleague.com/players/{}/'
link = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players'
payload = {
    'pageSize': '30',
    'compSeasons': '418',
    'altIds': 'true',
    'page': 0,
    'type': 'player',
    'id': '-1',
    'compSeasonId': '418'
}

football_pages = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['User-Agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'
    s.headers['referer'] = 'https://www.premierleague.com/'
    s.headers['origin'] = 'https://www.premierleague.com'


    while True:
        res = s.get(link,params=payload)
        if not res.json()['content']:break
        for item in res.json()['content']:
           football_pages.append(base.format(int(item['id'])))
        
        payload['page']+=1


for urls in football_pages:
    pages = requests.get(urls)
    try:
        table = pd.read_html(pages.text, attrs = {'class': 'honoursAwards'})[0]
        print(table)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing just this should work for you:

```
if table is not None: # or if table:
    tables=[item.text for item in table.find_all('th')] #error is here
    print(tables)
```

We are checking everytime `if table is None or not`, `if` table is `None` then don't do anything `else` work as usual.

Comment: In Python, we [idiomatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none) check for `None` with `is`.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel thankyou I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner than the answer above:

The if condition in Python checks whether the result of its evaluation is positive or not None. The 'NoneType' that you received in the error points exactly at that, that there is no table for one of the iterations, hence the evaluation returns None which is a NoneType.

```
if table: 
tables=[item.text for item in table.find_all('th')]
```