# Why I need to add a square bracket when I pass an instance as a parameter to class?

Tags: python, class, debugging

Below is my code:

```
class Person():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
        self.pet=None
    def print_name(self):
        print(f"The person's name is {self.name}")

class Employee(Person):
    raise_amt=1.04
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        super(Employee,self).__init__(name)
        self.salary=salary
    def apply_raise(self):
        self.salary=int(self.salary*self.raise_amt)

class Manager(Person):
    def __init__(self,name,salary,employees=None):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.salar=salary
        if employees==None:
            self.employees=[]
        else:
            self.employees=employees
    def add_emp(self,emp):
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)
    def print_emps(self):
        for emp in self.employees:
            emp.print_name()
```

When I try to run the program with below code, the error will pop up.

```
frank=Employee("Frank",120000)
john=Employee("John",10000)
sean=Manager("Sean",20000,frank)
sean.add_emp(john)
sean.print_emps()
```

The error I receive is `TypeError: argument of type 'Employee' is not iterable`.
However, when I put the square bracket around `[frank]`, the error is gone.
Can you help me to understand the reason?

Comment: You initialize Manager with an employees list of frank, but frank is not a list, it's an Employee.

Comment: An Employee indeed isn't iterable. A list _is_.

Comment: side note, please use `if employees is None` rather than `==` - [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919/what-is-the-difference-between-is-none-and-none)

Answer (score 4):

As others have said, in the `Manager` class `__init__` method, you allow an optional list of `Employees` to be given. If this list is given then the `Manager` instance will set it as the `employees` variable else it will set an empty list. In your case, you are initializing the `Manager` class with an instance of `Employee` and not a list.

#### For the future...

I recommend a few code style changes to help avoid these kind of issues:

- Add type annotations. This is not only great for you reading back your code, it enables linters to catch type errors before you run the code.
- Add more whitespace. Add spaces between operators, variables, parameters, functions, etc. It makes reading the code much easier.
- Use keyword arguments. In the example below, it's much easier to see what each argument is for and by extension, you can see `employees` is clearly a list.

```py
from typing import Optional, List

class Manager(Person):

    def __init__(self, name: str, salary: int, employees: Optional[List[Employee]] = None):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.salary = salary
        if employees is None:
            self.employees = []
        else:
            self.employees = employees

    def add_emp(self, emp: Employee):
        if emp not in self.employees:
            self.employees.append(emp)

    def print_emps(self):
        for emp in self.employees:
            emp.print_name()
```

And then when you're calling the classes:

```py
frank = Employee(name="Frank", salary=120000)
sean = Manager(name="Sean", salary=20000, employees=[frank])
```

Comment: You can also simplify: `self.employees = [] if employees is None else employees`. Feel free to add this in.

Comment: you should also kinda show from where you have imported those names [type hints] (considering it may not be clear to some), also using `Optional[List[Employee]]` seems a bit overkill IMO (especially for beginners) and a simple `list` would have sufficed but sure this is better

Answer (score -2):

Python is expecting `employees` to be a list of items, not a single item. Adding the square brackets around "frank" turns it from a simple Employee object to a list of Employee objects, with the first item being "frank".

You have differing code between your `__init__` and `add_emp` methods. In `__init__`, you set employees to the value specified (making it in your case an Employee object), whereas in `add_emp` you use `append()` to add the value to the existing values, maintaining the variable as a list.

Let's examine what your code actually does here:

- First you create two instances of `Employee` with names (strings) and salaries (ints)
- Then you create a Manager with a name, salary, and a single employee object assigned to `self.employees`
- You then check if the "John" employee is in sean's employees variable, but sean's employees variable is not a list of employees, it's just a single employee (frank). You're checking *if john is in frank*, not *if john is in a list of items that currently includes frank*.

If you only want to pass a single employee when creating each manager the best fix would be to change your `__init__` method as follows:

```
def __init__(self,name,salary,employees=None):
        super().__init__(name)
        self.salar=salary
        self.employees = []
        if employees:
            self.employees.append(employees)
```

If you want to pass in multiple employees, then do exactly as you are currently, pass a list e.g. `[frank]` not `frank` to the method.