# How to not return a key if its value is None in a recursive function

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have return statement within a recursive function that looks like this:

```
def recursive_function(data):
....
return {f'uid': uid,'title': title, 'string': string,'create-time': create_time, 'edit-time': edit_time, 'children': children, 'refs': refs}
```

Sometimes some of these values can be None (ex: when the title has a value, the string's value will be None, and vice-versa). The application I'm using does not recognize keys with None values, how do I prevent those keys from returning when the values are None?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is no specific function for that. You have to iterate through the dict entries and either remove the unwanted ones or build a new dict, usually with a dict comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using dictionary comprehension:

```
return {key:value for key,value in {f'uid': uid,'title': title, 'string': string,'create-time': create_time, 'edit-time': edit_time, 'children': children, 'refs': refs}.items() if value is not None }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly get non-`None` values from a dict directly. You can use a dictionary comprehension to retrieve the non-`None` values yourself instead.

```py
def recursive_function(data):
...
    original_dict = {'uid': uid,'title': title, 'string': string,
                     'create-time': create_time, 'edit-time': edit_time,
                     'children': children, 'refs': refs}

    return { key: value for key, value in
             original_dict.items() if value is not None }
```

Comment: Usage of `is not None` works, but ... comparisons using `is` are generally not a good idea in Python.

Comment: `None` is a singleton object. There is only ever 1 `None`. So comparing against it with `is` is the more Pythonic way of checking for `None`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257957/5901382

Comment: Yes, you are right. None is an exception from the general rule.