# SQL Alchemy: table.col == None or table.col.is_(None)?

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Running SQLAlchemy version < 2.0.0 and mysql. Wondering what the difference is between these

```
select_stmt.where(
    table.c.my_column.is_(None)
)
```

versus

```
select_stmt.where(
    table.c.my_column == None
)
```

Or even

```
select_stmt.where(
    table.c.my_column.is_(null())
)
```

Answer (score 2):

All of these statements generate the same SQL (`WHERE my_column IS NULL`), so on that basis there is no difference. However

- some linters may complain about `== None`, but not about `is_`
  (see [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3257919/5320906) for some discussion of `is None` vs  `== None` in general Python code).
- `== None` may be easier to work with when dynamically constructing filters.

For example, if we have a dictionary of column names and values and we want to find rows that match it we can do:

```py
criteria = [tbl.c[k] == v for k, v in some_dict.items()]
q = select(tbl).where(and_(*citeria))
```

This would be more complicated to implement if we had to use `is_` instead of `==` if a value was `None`.