# Flask app with boto3 (Dynamodb) - inconsistent data retrieval (solved)

Tags: flask, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a AWS IoT configuration rule to save messages from MQTT to a DynamoDB v2 table. The saving process is working fine - I've an arduino running a code that is sending data to MQTT and normally saving data to the DynamoDb.

I also have an application (flask) running on a EC2. The problem is that the data retrieval is totally inconsistent. At this moment I'm writing, if I perform a scan using AWS console, I have 58 entries (I have to click on "retrieve next page", otherwise I would only see 50 items). But when I call my app , sometimes I see 50 items, sometimes 54... sometimes even 58!

If I restart apache2 server, it appears that will correctly count.

Below is the code I'm running. Any thoughts?

```
from flask import Flask
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from datetime import datetime

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'access_key'
REGION_NAME = 'region'

dynamodb = boto3.resource(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id     = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name           = REGION_NAME
)

table = dynamodb.Table('my_db')

lastEvaluatedKey = None
items = []

#I'm doing this below to get all pages
while True:
    if lastEvaluatedKey == None:
        response = table.scan()
    else:
        response = table.scan(
        ExclusiveStartKey=lastEvaluatedKey
    )

    items.extend(response['Items'])

    if 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
        lastEvaluatedKey = response['LastEvaluatedKey']
    else:
        break

#localDateTime is my sortKey
sorted_items = sorted(items, key=lambda x: datetime.strptime(x['localDateTime'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'), reverse=True)

app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def my_app():
    return sorted_items
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

I'm trying to get all data from dynamoDb

I also tried using this AWS example, with `paginator`, but had the same issue. First time I run after restarting apache2, I have the right number of items. Then I add some items, but they don't appear until I restart apache2:

```
from flask import Flask
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr
from datetime import datetime

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'key'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'secret'
REGION_NAME = 'region'

dynamodb = boto3.client(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id     = AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    aws_secret_access_key = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    region_name           = REGION_NAME
)

paginator = dynamodb.get_paginator('query')
response = paginator.paginate(TableName='my-table',
        KeyConditionExpression="id = :id",
        ExpressionAttributeValues= {
            ":id": {
                "S": "my_id"
                }
            }
        )

items = []

for page in response:
    items.append(page['Items'])


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')

def my_app():
    return items[0]
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run()
```

Comment: In [general](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257919), Python programmers write `if x is None`, rather than `if x == None`.

Comment: Also, be aware that boto3 supports paginators e.g. for [DynamoDB scan](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/dynamodb-implement-pagination).

Comment: Your app server should scan the table each time the / route is hit. As the code is written, it appears to scan the table one time per process, when the app process is launched, and thereafter will always yield the same results for any GET request that happens to hit that same process (because `sorted_items` never changes in that specific process).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I’ve consolidated in only one question and will use the comment feature. 

I understand your point , but this is how I see in examples. Any idea on how to process and scan  for any GET?

Comment: As in the comment below I've moved everything inside def my_app() and it's working! thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your pagination logic is amiss. Try this implementation:

```
response = table.scan()
data = response['Items']

while 'LastEvaluatedKey' in response:
    response = table.scan(ExclusiveStartKey=response['LastEvaluatedKey'])
    data.extend(response['Items'])
```

Comment: I've tried to implement this but still the same problem. Only when I restart apache2 it will retrieve the correct number of items.

Comment: This is because you only call DynamoDB when you start your server. So you do obtain the correct number intially. You should call the API everytime you need the accurate information from the table, not only on application init.

Comment: That was correct.. I've moved everything inside `def my_app()` and it's working! thanks.

Comment: To be clear, while the pagination code may have been incorrect, it was not the root cause of the failure. That was caused by your scan code executing outside, and long before, your route handler was executed in response to a client request. Consequently the route handler always returned some cached collection of items, not the live collection of items.