# `id` function in Python 2.7, `is` operator, object identity and user-defined methods

Tags: python, python-2.7, identity, equality

The results from the code below in Python 2.7 struck me as a contradiction. The `is` operator is supposed to work with object identity and so is `id`. But their results diverge when I'm looking at a user-defined method. Why is that?

```
py-mach >>class Hello(object):
...  def hello():
...    pass
...
py-mach >>Hello.hello is Hello.hello
False
py-mach >>id(Hello.hello) - id(Hello.hello)
0
```

I found the following excerpt from the description of the [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) somewhat useful. But it didn't really make everything clear. Why does the `id` function return the same integer if the user-defined method objects are constructed anew each time?

> User-defined method objects may be created when getting an attribute of a class (perhaps via an instance of that class), if that attribute is a user-defined function object, an unbound user-defined method object, or a class method object. When the attribute is a user-defined method object, a new method object is only created if the class from which it is being retrieved is the same as, or a derived class of, the class stored in the original method object; otherwise, the original method object is used as it is.

Comment: @user2357112 -- I think OP understands that part "Why does the `id` function return the same integer if the user-defined method objects are constructed anew each time?".  A better dupe would be http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877230/748858

Comment: @mgilson: Yep, which is why I reopened. I need to stop using the dupehammer so hastily.

Comment: @user2357112 -- I kinda liked it better back in the day when it required 4 more people to agree with me that it was a dupe -- These days I'm more reluctant to bring the dupehammer down...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The Python documentation for the [id function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) states:

> Return the "identity" of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.**

(emphasis mine)

When you do `id(Hello.hello) == id(Hello.hello)`, the method object is created only briefly and is considered "dead" after the first call to 'id'. Because of the call to `id`, you only need `Hello.hello` to be alive for a short period of time -- enough to obtain the id. Once you get that id, the object is dead and the second `Hello.hello` can reuse that address, which makes it appear as if the two objects have the same id.

This is in contrast to doing `Hello.hello is Hello.hello` -- both instances have to live long enough to be compared to each other, so you end up having two live instances.

If you instead tried:

```
>>> a = Hello.hello
>>> b = Hello.hello
>>> id(a) == id(b)
False
```

...you'd get the expected value of `False`.

Comment: In theory `Hello.hello is Hello.hello` could delete its reference of the first `Hello.hello` before asking the second for its `id`.

Answer (score 8):

This is a "simple" consequence of how the memory allocator works.  It is very similar to the case:

```
>>> id([]) == id([])
True
```

Basically python doesn't guarantee that ID's don't get reused -- it only guarantees that the id is unique *as long as the object is alive*.  In this case, the first object being passed to `id` is dead after the call to `id` and (C)python re-uses that `id` when creating the second object.

Never rely on this behavior as it is *allowed* by the language reference, but certainly not *required*.