# Identity of class methods

Tags: python

Given the class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def my_class_method(cls):
        return None
```

why does

```
MyClass.my_class_method is MyClass.my_class_method
```

evaluate to `False`, while this

```
id(MyClass.my_class_method) == id(MyClass.my_class_method)
```

is `True`?

Comment: I am not sure if this really is a duplicate of the referenced question. I understand that two empty lists, created independently of each other are not the same object. In this example however the `type` instances `MyClass` *are* the same object ( `MyClass is MyClass` is `True`). Why does the same not hold for its bound method `my_class_method`?

Comment: @Ashwini Chaudhary I may not be trying hard enough... but looking through your duplicate, I still feel like this situation is _different_. Notice that in this scenario the OP is always using the same object, `MyClass.my_class_method`, so it's unlike the situation where one might do `(id({}) == id({}))`. It makes perfect sense that the second example would return `True`. So the real question (and which isn't really answered IMO in your linked duplicate) is why the `is` operator not returning `True` as with `id()`.

Comment: @Eithos `MyClass.my_class_method` is not the same object, each invocation of class method or instance method actually returns a new wrapper.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary That was my thinking too, actually. I'm not totally unfamiliar with the logic going on underneath. But try this: `def getID(obj):
    objID = id(obj)
    print objID
    return objID` And then, `print getID(MyClass.my_class_method) is getID(MyClass.my_class_method)` What's very weird about the output here is that I get something like `34298328 34298328 False`. How could the `is` operator in a situation like this not return `True` when the id fetched is the same? Something tells me I may not be seeing what's obvious in front of me ;P

Comment: @Eithos From [data-model](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html) page: Note that the transformation from function object to (unbound or bound) method object **happens each time the attribute is retrieved** from the class or instance.

Comment: @ashwini I've chosen to re-open as although similar, I think this Q deserves a more specific answer - feel free to do so :p

Comment: @Eithos That's because once the function `getID` has finished executing Python can re-use the same memory space, hence same IDs. As simple as that.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I agree, that's exactly what I was assuming. But in that case, _why isn't it returning `True`_? Especially when really all it should be doing is `34298328 is 34298328`, no? That _definitely_ should return `True`, and it does if I just write it out that way.

Comment: @Eithos `34298328 is 34298328` is different than `getID(MyClass.my_class_method) is getID(MyClass.my_class_method)`, integers literals can be cached by CPython, but the integers returned by those function calls cannot be considered literals.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary Huh, interesting. You got me there =P. I'll have to do some extra reading tomorrow when I wake up. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `classmethod` decorator wraps the method in a descriptor.
`MyClass.my_class_method` does the same as the code `MyClass.__dict__['my_class_method'].__get__(None, MyClass)`; `__get__`  returns a distinct **bound method** wrapper for each invocation, thus the 2 are distinct objects and `is` fails.

The [`id` being the same is just a (common) coincidence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython), since `id` in CPython is calculated based on the address where the object resides; when the `id` of the first bound method wrapper is calculated, the reference count on that wrapper is decreased and the wrapper is released; by happenstance the second one will be allocated at the exactly same address. `id(obj)` is guaranteed to be distinct only for each currently living object.

---

In Python 2 the former was true for **unbound** methods as well:

```
>>> class MyClass():   
...     def x(self):
...         pass
... 
>>> MyClass.x
<unbound method MyClass.x>
>>> MyClass.x is MyClass.x
False
```

In Python 3 the unbound method semantics were changed, and now

```
>>> class MyClass():   
...    def x(self):
...        pass
...
>>> MyClass.x
<function __main__.x>
>>> MyClass.x is MyClass.x
True
```

The unbound instance methods are bare functions in Python 3 and each lookup yields the same object.