# Python “is” statement: unexpected behavior when comparing unbound method

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, interpreter

In Python 2.7.9, when I assign a unbound method to a new attribute, and compare them by `is` statement, the result is `False`:

```
In [1]: class A(object):
   ...:     def a(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [2]: A._a = A.a

In [3]: print A.a, A._a
<unbound method A.a> <unbound method A.a>

In [4]: print id(A.a), id(A._a)
4499595904 4499595904

In [5]: A.a is A._a
Out[5]: False
```

This is very counter-intuitive and I could not find any reference or documentation to explain this behavior. What's more, when I test the same code in Python 3.4.2, the result turned to be `True`. I'm guessing that it's a bug in Python 2.7 but got fixed in Python 3, can anyone help me find the actual reason why this happen?

Comment: mb it is because a is a method and _a is link.

Comment: This question is gonna be good..

Comment: This is the answer I think: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13348031/python-bound-and-unbound-method-object

Comment: As for why the IDs are the same, see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython).