# How can 2 objects be considered not equal and not identicial by Python, but have the same id?

Tags: python, object, hash, equality

This code snippet is really puzzling me:

```
class O(object):
    pass
O() == O()             # False
O() is O()             # False
hash(O()) == hash(O()) # True !
id(O()) == id(O())     # True !!!
```

I always thought that the `is` operator was comparing `id`s, and that the default instance equality check (`==`) also compared `id`s, or at least `hash`es:

- [`x is y` is true if and only if x and y are the same object](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not-in)
- [If no `__cmp__()`, `__eq__()` or `__ne__()` operation is defined, class instances are compared by object identity (“address”)](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__cmp__)

How can 2 class instances share the same `id`, but not be equal in any way ??

I'm using CPython 2.7.6.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython).

In CPython, `id` returns the pointer where the data is stored.

In your example the GC is removing the old object before the comparinson. The second object is placed where the first was, thus returning the same value for `id`.

Answer (score 4):

They don't "share the same id". In CPython (the most-used implementation) the `id` function returns the memory address of the Python object it is given as an argument. What's happening is that the objects are being garbage-collected, and the memory is being re-used. `id`s are only guaranteed unique for objects existing simultaneously. If you bind the objects to names you get a more sensible result:

```
>>> class O(object):
...     pass
...
>>> o1 = O() ; o2 = O()
>>> o1 == o2
False
>>> o1 is o2
False
>>> hash(o1) == hash(o2)
False
>>> id(o1) == id(o2)
False
```

Comment: I believe, you should point out that in some cases Python implicitly reuses an object (e.g. an integer) when one may think a new one gets created, e.g. `a=0; b=0; id(a) == id(b)` return `True`.

Comment: Special treatment of certain small-valued integers is a specific detail of the CPython implementation, but isn't relevant to this question. Plus, the code `id(a) == id(b)` is _exactly_ equivalent to `a is b` - in fact, that's the definition