# Understanding iterable types in comparisons

Tags: python, iterator

Recently I ran into cosmologicon's [pywats](https://github.com/cosmologicon/pywat) and now try to understand part about fun with iterators:

```
>>> a = 2, 1, 3
>>> sorted(a) == sorted(a)
True
>>> reversed(a) == reversed(a)
False
```

Ok, `sorted(a)` returns a `list` and `sorted(a) == sorted(a)` becomes just a two lists comparision. But `reversed(a)` returns `reversed object`. So why these reversed objects are different? And id's comparision makes me even more confused:

```
>>> id(reversed(a)) == id(reversed(a))
True
```

Comment: Iterators generally compare as False, because you can't know what you'll get from iterating over them until you do so.

Comment: So comparison returns False because of reversed `__eq__` implementation?

Comment: `sorted` returns a list.  A more fair comparison would be between `iter(a)` and `reversed(a)`.

Comment: Comparing IDs this way is a classic mistake: [Why does `id({}) == id({})` and `id([]) == id([])` in CPython?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The basic reason why `id(reversed(a) == id(reversed(a)` returns `True` , whereas `reversed(a) == reversed(a)` returns `False` , can be seen from the below example using custom classes -

```
>>> class CA:
...     def __del__(self):
...             print('deleted', self)
...     def __init__(self):
...             print('inited', self)
...
>>> CA() == CA()
inited <__main__.CA object at 0x021B8050>
inited <__main__.CA object at 0x021B8110>
deleted <__main__.CA object at 0x021B8050>
deleted <__main__.CA object at 0x021B8110>
False
>>> id(CA()) == id(CA())
inited <__main__.CA object at 0x021B80F0>
deleted <__main__.CA object at 0x021B80F0>
inited <__main__.CA object at 0x021B80F0>
deleted <__main__.CA object at 0x021B80F0>
True
```

As you can see when you did `customobject == customobject` , the object that was created on the fly was not destroyed until after the comparison occurred, this is because that object was required for the comparison.

But in case of `id(co) == id(co)` , the custom object created was passed to `id()` function, and then only the result of `id` function is required for comparison , so the object that was created has no reference left, and hence the object was *garbage collected*, and then when the Python interpreter recreated a new object for the right side of `==` operation, it reused the space that was freed previously. Hence, the `id` for both came as same.

This above behavior is an implementation detail of CPython (it may/may not differ in other implementations of Python) . And you should never rely on the equality of `ids` . For example in the below case it gives the wrong result -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> id(reversed(a)) == id(reversed(b))
True
```

The reason for this is again as explained above (garbage collection of the `reversed` object created for `reversed(a)` before creation of reversed object for `reversed(b)`).

---

If the lists are large, I think the most memory efficient and most probably the fastest method to compare equality for two iterators would be to use [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#all) built-in function along with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function for Python 3.x (or [`itertools.izip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip) for Python 2.x).

Example for Python 3.x -

```
all(x==y for x,y in zip(aiterator,biterator))
```

Example for Python 2.x -

```
from itertools import izip
all(x==y for x,y in izip(aiterator,biterator))
```

This is because `all()` short circuits at the first False value is encounters, and `zip() in Python 3.x returns an iterator which yields out the corresponding elements from both the different iterators. This does not need to create a separate list in memory.

Demo -

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]
>>> b = [4,5,6]
>>> all(x==y for x,y in zip(reversed(a),reversed(b)))
False
>>> all(x==y for x,y in zip(reversed(a),reversed(a)))
True
```

Comment: Alright! That explains why `x=reversed(a)` `y=reversed(a)` `id(x)==id(y)` gives `False`. Thank you.

Comment: Now it definitely makes sense for me! So `reversed(a) == reversed(a)` is actually a comparison of two different objects!

Comment: @valentjedi: note that the behavior for `id()` is CPython-specific. Don't rely on it if you want your code to be portable and compatible with future versions of CPython.

Answer (score 7):

`sorted` returns a list, whereas `reversed` returns a `reversed` object and is a different object. If you were to cast the result of `reversed` to a list before comparison, they will be equal.

```
In [8]: reversed(a)
Out[8]: <reversed at 0x2c98d30>

In [9]: reversed(a)
Out[9]: <reversed at 0x2c989b0>
```

Answer (score 3):

`reversed` returns an iterable that doesn't implement a specific `__eq__` operator and therefore is compared using identity.

The confusion about `id(reversed(a)) == id(reversed(a))` is because after evaluating the first `id(...)` call the iterable can be disposed (nothing references it) and the second iterable may be reallocated at the very same memory address when the second `id(...)` call is done. This is however just a coincidence.

Try

```
ra1 = reversed(a)
ra2 = reversed(a)
```

and compare `id(ra1)` with `id(ra2)` and you will see they are different numbers (because in this case the iterable objects cannot be deallocated as they're referenced by `ra1`/`ra2` variables).

Answer (score 0):

You may try `list(reversed(a)) ==list(reversed(a))`  will return `True`

```
list(reversed(a))
[3, 2, 1]
```

once try

```
>>> v = id(reversed(a))
>>> n = id(reversed(a))
>>> v == n
False
```

again

```
>>> v = id(reversed(a))
>>> n = id(reversed(a))
>>> n1 = id(reversed(a)) 
>>> v == n1
True
```

Comment: `v == n1` ==> `True` how? Your answer hardly explains anything.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary try  `id(reversed(a))`  continuously for 5 to 10 times in python Shell. you will get some repeat of ID's

Comment: That's because due to garbage collection of older objects CPython can re-use that memory space, if there are already reference(s) to an object then a new object will use some different ID.