# Same object issue in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, oop, object

I observed that you will get the same object (at the same address) as in the example code below. I was expecting that each time the function runs, I would get a distinct one. I searched online but failed to find the explanation for this.

Any clarification of why this happens / any advice on how I can get a **distinct** object each time would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

```
>>> class A:
...   pass
>>>
>>> def test():
...   print A()
... 
>>> test()
<__main__.A instance at 0x10d2ac320>
>>> test()
<__main__.A instance at 0x10d2ac320>
```

Comment: Especially see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3877275/918959)

Answer (score 4):

You *are* getting a distinct object each time.

What is happening is that the first distinct object is alive, gets printed and then gets reaped by the garbage collector.  Then a new object is created and it happens to get the same memory location that the last object had (and therefore the same ID).  This is actually a lot more common than you might expect (due to the implementation of the CPython memory allocator) and [variants of this pop up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3877230/748858) in Stackoverflow questions from time to time.

Note that python only guarantees that two objects will never have the same ID if they have an overlapping lifetime.  From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) for `id`:

> Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer (or long integer) which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. **Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.**

To see that you can get distinct objects, just keep a reference to the objects that are returned.  That will prevent the objects from being reaped by the garbage collector:

```
a = test()
b = test()
a is b
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Makes a lot of sense.