# Numpy arrays changing id

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

What is happening here? It seems like the id locations of the array is not remaining steady maybe?is operator is returning False even thought the ids are same. then after printing the arrays the ids of elements are changing. Any explanations?

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(27)
b = a[1:5]
a[0] is b[1] #False
id(a[0]) #40038736L
id(b[1]) #40038736L
a #prints the array
id(b[1]) #40038712L
id(a[0]) #40038712L
b[0] #1
a[1] #1
id(b[0]) #40038712L
id(a[1]) #40038784L
```

Comment: This may work with lists which contain pointers to objects.  But an array stores values in a data buffer.  `a[2]` is a new object with a reference to that buffer, but its `id` has nothing to do with `a` or the databuffer.  So `id` is not useful when working with arrays.

Comment: Half-duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython. I wish we had a "split duplicate" feature.

Answer (score 2):

First test with a list:

```
In [1109]: a=[0,1,2,3,4]
In [1112]: b=a[1:3]

In [1113]: id(a[1])
Out[1113]: 139407616
In [1114]: id(b[0])
Out[1114]: 139407616

In [1115]: a[1] is b[0]
Out[1115]: True
```

later I tried

```
In [1129]: id(1)
Out[1129]: 139407616
```

So the object in `a[1]` is consistently the integer `1` (`id` of integers is a bit tricky, and implementation dependent).

But with an array:

```
In [1118]: aa=np.arange(5)
In [1119]: ba=aa[1:]

In [1121]: aa[1]
Out[1121]: 1
In [1122]: ba[0]
Out[1122]: 1
In [1123]: id(aa[1])
Out[1123]: 2925837264
In [1124]: id(ba[0])
Out[1124]: 2925836912
```

`id` are totally different; in fact they change with each access:

```
In [1125]: id(aa[1])
Out[1125]: 2925837136
In [1126]: id(ba[0])
Out[1126]: 2925835104
```

That's because `aa[1]` isn't just the integer `1`.  It is a `np.int32` object.

```
In [1127]: type(aa[1])
Out[1127]: numpy.int32
```

In contrast to a list, values of an array are stored as bytes in a `databuffer`.  `b[1:]` is a `view` and accesses the same data buffer.  But `a[1]` is a new object that contains a reference to that data buffer.  In contrast to the list case, `a[1]` is not the 2nd object in `a`.

In general, `id` is not useful when working with arrays, and the `is` test is also not useful.  Use `==` or `isclose` (for floats).

================

A way to see where the values of `aa` are stored is with:

```
In [1137]: aa.__array_interface__
Out[1137]: 
{'data': (179274256, False),      # 'id' so to speak of the databuffer
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (5,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
In [1138]: ba.__array_interface__
Out[1138]: 
{'data': (179274260, False),    # this is 4 bytes larger
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (4,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

the `data` pointer for the 2 arrays is related because `ba` is a `view`.

`aa[1]` is array-like, and too has a data buffer, but it isn't a view.

```
In [1139]: aa[1].__array_interface__
Out[1139]: 
{'__ref': array(1),
 'data': (182178952, False),
 ...}
```

Comment: Would you mind putting a little more light on why the ids are changing with each access for aa[1]. Is it getting garbage collected and created afresh each time id on it is called?

Comment: It's not a matter of garbage collection.  `aa[1]` is produced by a method call, `aa.__getitem__((1))`.  It is creating a new `np.int32` object each time.