# numpy array shows same id after changing values

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

#### I have created 2 numpy arrays.

1. Original
2. Cloned

Cloned is a copy of original array. I *changed an element* in cloned array. I am checking id of `original` and `cloned` array  using **is** keyword. It returns `false`. But when I print id of both elements, it is same.

I know about [peephole optimization techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peephole_optimization) and numbers from -5 to 256 is stored at same address in python. But here I have changed value to 400 (> 256). Still it shows same id. WHY?

Please correct me if I am wrong. I am new to numpy arrays

```
import numpy as np

original = np.array([
    [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    [6, 7, 9, 10, 11]
])


# Copying array "original" to "cloned"
cloned = original.copy()

# Changing first element of Cloned Array
cloned[0, 1] = 400

print(id(cloned[0, 1]))
print(id(original[0, 1]))

print(id(cloned[0, 1]) is id(original[0, 1]))
```

### Output:

140132171232408
`id is same`

140132171232408
`id is same`

False
`is returns false although id is same`

Comment: `original[0,1]` is numpy object created on-the-fly to show the value at that slot.  It is not the value, nor the location in the array.  So its `id` doesn't tell you any thing useful,

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40196986/numpy-arrays-changing-id

Answer (score 0):

The **is** keyword is used to test if two variables refer to the same object, not to check if they are equal. Use *==* instead as following:

```
print(id(cloned[0, 1]) == id(original[0, 1]))
# Returns True
```

Apparently id() function return the same value but different objects therefore using **is** operator does not work.

Comment: My partial solved is solved. Thank you for that. 
My another question is that why `id` is same? Although 400 and 2 are two different values.