# Do Python nested functions copy-on-could-write?

Tags: python, function, nested, copy-on-write

Please forgive a Python enthusiast a mostly academic question.

I was interested in the cost, if any, of nested functions - not the functionally justified ones that utilize closure etc., but the keep the outer namespace tidy variety.

So I did a simple measurement:

```
def inner(x):
    return x*x

def flat(x):
    return inner(x)

def nested(x):
    def inner(x):
        return x*x
    return inner(x)

# just to get a feel of the cost of having two more lines
def fake_nested(x):
    y = x
    z = x
    return inner(x)

from timeit import timeit

print(timeit('f(3)', globals=dict(f=flat)))
print(timeit('f(3)', globals=dict(f=nested)))
print(timeit('f(3)', globals=dict(f=fake_nested)))

# 0.17055258399341255
# 0.23098028398817405
# 0.19381927204085514
```

So it seems that there is some overhead and it appears to be more than would be explained by having two more lines.

It seems, however, that the inner `def` statement is not evaluated each time the outer function is called, indeed the inner function object appears to be cached:

```
def nested(x):
    def inner(x):
        return x*x
    print(id(inner), id(inner.__code__), id(inner.__closure__))
    return inner(x)

nested(3)
x = [list(range(i)) for i in range(5000)] # create some memory pressure
nested(3)

# 139876371445960 139876372477824 8845216
# 139876371445960 139876372477824 8845216
```

Looking for other things that might add to the longer runtime I stumbled over the following nerdgasm:

```
def nested(x):
    def inner(x):
        return x*x
    print(id(inner), id(inner.__code__), id(inner.__closure__))
    return inner

nested(3)
x = [list(range(i)) for i in range(5000)] # create some memory pressure
a = nested(3)
x = [list(range(i)) for i in range(5000)] # create some memory pressure
nested(3)

# 139906265032768 139906264446704 8845216
# 139906265032768 139906264446704 8845216
# 139906264258624 139906264446704 8845216
```

It seems that if Python detects that there is an outer reference to the cached nested function, then it creates a new function object.

Now - assuming my reasoning so far is not completely off - my question: **What is this good for?**

My first idea was "Ok, if the user has a reference to the cached function, they may have messsed with it, so better make a clean new one." But on second thoughts that doesn't seem to wash because the copy is not a deep copy and also what if the user messes with the function and then throws the reference away?

Supplementary question: Does Python do any other fiendishly clever things behind the scenes? And is this at all related to the slower execution of nested compared to flat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the **time difference**, a look at the bytecode of the two functions provides some hints. Comparison between `nested()` and `fake_nested()` shows that whereas `fake_nested` just loads already defined global function `inner()`, nested has to create this function. There will be some overhead here whereas the other operations will be relatively fast.

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(flat)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (inner)
              3 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              9 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(nested)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object inner at 0x7f2958a33830, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
              3 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               1 (inner)

  4           9 LOAD_FAST                1 (inner)
             12 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(fake_nested)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 STORE_FAST               1 (y)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              9 STORE_FAST               2 (z)

  4          12 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (inner)
             15 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 RETURN_VALUE
```

As for the **inner function caching part**, the other answer already clarifies that a new `inner()` function will be created every time nested() is run. To see this more clearly see the following variation on `nested()`, `cond_nested()` which creates same functions with two different names based on a flag. First time this runs with a `False` flag second function `inner2()` is created. Next when I change the flag to `True` the first function `inner1()` is created and the memory occupied by second function `inner2()` is freed. So if I run again with `True` flag, the first function is again created and is assigned a memory that was occupied by second function which is free now.

```
>>> def cond_nested(x, flag=False):
...     if flag:
...         def inner1(x):
...             return x*x                                                                                                                           
...         cond_nested.func = inner1
...         print id(inner1)                                                                                                                         
...         return inner1(x)
...     else:
...         def inner2(x):                                                                                                                           
...             return x*x
...         cond_nested.func = inner2
...         print id(inner2)
...         return inner2(x)
... 
>>> cond_nested(2)
139815557561112
4
>>> cond_nested.func
<function inner2 at 0x7f2958a47b18>
>>> cond_nested(2, flag=True)
139815557561352
4
>>> cond_nested.func
<function inner1 at 0x7f2958a47c08>
>>> cond_nested(3, flag=True)
139815557561112
9
>>> cond_nested.func
<function inner1 at 0x7f2958a47b18>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really must look into `dis` seems very useful. - Re the memory reusage issue, as I mentioned to the other answerer I was aware of that, but your examle is still instructive. `inner2` and the second `inner1` even have different code objects but still the same id. Also, in that example creating the list of lists `x` in between does work to prevent the same memory from being used. I wish I'd understand that memory management stuff better!

Comment: Two perfectly good answers. But yours has a bit more substance than @Antti's so I'm accepting it. Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Your reasoning is completely off. Python always creates a new function object **each** time a `def` is encountered in the normal program flow - no exceptions.

It is just that in **CPython** the `id` of the newly created function likely is the same as that of the old. See [*"Why does id({}) == id({}) and id([]) == id([]) in CPython?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython).

Now, if you saved a reference to the inner function, it is not deleted before the next function is created, and naturally the new function cannot coexist at the same memory address.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thougt I guarded against that particular gotcha by creating lots of new objects between when the reference is dropped and the new one is created. Does that not work?

Comment: I thought I even thought of that. I'm sure in my list of lists there is one sublist of the right size! Well, maybe one is not enough. - Ok,  you've convinved me. Maybe, explain this memory thing a bit in your answer and maybe whether the code and closure objects are cached and I'll gladly accept it.