# Why one needs id() in Python if there is already hash()

Tags: python, hash, objectid

The Python documentation for the `id()` function says

> id(object)
>   Return the “identity” of an object. This is an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime. Two objects with non-overlapping lifetimes may have the same id() value.

So, practically, it guaranties the uniqueness as an hash function, but only within the object lifespan and without the cool thing that an hash is hardly reconstructable.

Why should one use `id()`?

Comment: One reason: "Numeric values that compare equal have the same hash value (even if they are of different types, as is the case for 1 and 1.0)."  That's not the case for id().

Comment: Because you want an integer which is guaranteed to be unique and constant for this object during its lifetime?

Answer (score 5):

`hash` is equal for *equal* objects, and may be equal even for unequal objects. `hash` doesn't even exist for mutable objects.

`id` is guaranteed to be unique for an object during its lifetime, and it doesn't care about mutation.

The use cases are completely different.

```
>>> x, y, z = 1, 1.0, [1]
>>> hash(x), hash(y)
(1, 1)
>>> hash(z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
>>> id(x), id(y)
(10832608, 139668416746072)
>>> id(z)
139668282136008
>>> z.append(2)
>>> id(z)
139668282136008
>>> hash(-1), hash(-2)
(-2, -2)
```

Comment: anyway, `id(str(1)) == id(str(1))` is true!

Comment: @Nisba, yes, that's an implementation detail / optimization, true because `1` is automatically interned, so there's only one instance of it.

Comment: @Nisba: That's because Python happens to reuse the same object. Don't use `id` or `is` on immutable primitives; doing so is basically useless.

Comment: It does't take too much work to get distinct `str` objects: `x = "12"; y = x[0] + x[1]` was sufficient in one test.

Comment: @user2357112 please see the edit I am going to write

Comment: @Nisba: If you're about to change your question to ask more things it didn't ask previously, don't.

Comment: ...on which point, see [What to do when someone answers: Don't be a chameleon, don't be a vandal](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332820/what-to-do-when-someone-answers-dont-be-a-chameleon-dont-be-a-vandal) -- the former being immediately relevant.

Comment: @chepner but `id("12") == id("1"+"2")` is True

Comment: @user2357112 ok. I defined an empty class and two different instances have the same ids, even if now it is not a primitive

Comment: @Nisba, yup -- that's something a peephole optimizer can do in the bytecode ahead-of-time, but like all implementation-defined optimizations, it's unsafe to rely on either presence or lack thereof.

Comment: @Nisba: [*During its lifetime.*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython)

Comment: @Nisba Yes, which is why I specifically used `x[0] + x[1]` in my example. CPython can optimize literals more than it can object references. Also, even for longer strings, the literals passed to `id` are anonymous and the temporary object can be reclaimed after the call to `id` completes, allowing the object id to be reused for the second one.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of the `id` function in python like a sort of pointer, it is a unique number for the that object. so two identical objects can have the same hash, but different ids (unless the hash is reference based, in which case it isn't guaranteed to return the same hash on different processes)

check this answer out as well [What is the id( ) function used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15667189/what-is-the-id-function-used-for)

Comment: I think pointers and id are very different concepts, except for CPython

Comment: I am aware of that, I will update my answer to clarify, but in a sense, it is the representation of an instance, just as a pointer is.