# why is the class method called by instance and class not the same thing

Tags: python, class-method

for start, let's define a class and instance of the class

```
class c:
    @classmethod
    def m(cls, a):
        return a + 1
a = c()
```

those methods are used the same way

```
>>> c.m(5), a.m(5)
6, 6
```

and `cls` in both cases is `c`

but `c.m is a.m` is `False`
and `c.m == a.m` is `True`

why is the class method called by instance and class not the same and why am I able to call it even by an instance of that class

it would make sense if `cls` were not the same in both cases

EDIT:

I already knew the difference between `is` and `==`

I was already successfully using `is` to check if two classes are the same
(`type(a) is int` for example), but I did learn I should use it for `is None`, so thanks anyway for leading me to that page

**My question actually was why are they not the same object**

they even have same ID `id(a.m) == id(c.m)`

Comment: You used the wrong operator to test for equality. They're indeed the same, just different copies of the same thing.

Comment: Related: [Does this already answer your question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python)

Comment: It's not clear to me that this is an issue of confusion between `is` and `==`.  The OP is using both so seems to know they are different.  The question is *why* they are different when the two objects seem to give the same behavior.

Comment: "they even have same ID" - [no they don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython).

Comment: @user2357112 "they even have same ID" yes they do. I double checked: I recreated exactly the same class with same names and it is the same. try doing `id(a.m), id(c.m)` and see what comes out

Comment: The `a.m` and `c.m` you were dealing with in `a.m is c.m` didn't have the same IDs. The `a.m` and `c.m` in `id(a.m) == id(c.m)` had equal IDs, but those were different objects from the ones in the `is` comparison.

Comment: @user2357112 why would they be different objects from ones in `is`

Comment: Accessing a method creates a new method object.

Comment: @user2357112  I accessed method object in both cases. Can you explain more thoroughly what you meant

Comment: @Superior: An expression like `obj.meth` creates a new method object *every time* you evaluate the expression.