# Large memory footprint of integers compared with result of sys.getsizeof()

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, cpython, python-internals

Python-Integer-objects in the range `[1,2^30)` need `28` byte, as provided by `sys.getsizeof()` and explained for example in [this SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23016640/5769463).

However, when I measure the memory footprint with the following script:

```
#int_list.py:
import sys

N=int(sys.argv[1])
lst=[0]*N            # no overallocation

for i in range(N):
    lst[i]=1000+i    # ints not from integer pool
```

via

```
/usr/bin/time -fpeak_used_memory:%M python3 int_list.py <N>
```

I get the following peak memory values (Linux-x64, Python 3.6.2):

```
   N     Peak memory in Kb        bytes/integer
-------------------------------------------   
   1            9220              
   1e7        404712                40.50 
   2e7        800612                40.52 
   3e7       1196204                40.52
   4e7       1591948                40.52
```

So it looks as if `40.5` bytes are needed per one integer object, i.e. `12.5` bytes more than yielded by `sys.getsizeof()`.

Additional `8` bytes are easy to explain - the list `lst` doesn't hold the integer objects, but references to  them - that means an additonal pointer, i.e. `8` bytes, are needed.

However, what about the other `4.5` bytes, what are they used for?

The following causes can be ruled out:

- size of integer-objects are variable, but `10^7` is smaller than `2^30` and thus all integer will be `28` bytes large.
- There is no overallocation in the list `lst`, which can be easily checked via `sys.getsizeof(lst)` which yields `8` times the number of elements, plus a very small overhead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Nathan's suggestion is surprisingly not the solution, due to some subtly details of CPython's `longint`-implementation. With his explanation, the memory footprint for

```
...
lst[i] = (1<<30)+i
```

should still be `40.52`, because `sys.sizeof(1<<30)` is `32`, but the measurements show it to be `48.56`. On the other hand, for

```
...
lst[i] = (1<<60)+i
```

the footprint is still `48.56`, despite the fact, that `sys.sizeof(1<<60)` is `36`.

The reason: the `sys.getsizeof()` doesn't tell us the real memory footprint for the result of  a summation, i.e. `a+b` which is

- 32 bytes for `1000+i`
- 36 bytes for `(1<<30)+i`
- 40 bytes for `(1<<60)+i`

That happens because when two integers are added in [`x_add`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a10d426bab66a4e1f20d5e1b9aee3dbb435cf309/Objects/longobject.c#L3157-L3187), the resulting integer has at first one "digit", i.e. 4 bytes, more than the maximum of `a` and `b`:

```
static PyLongObject *
x_add(PyLongObject *a, PyLongObject *b)
{
    Py_ssize_t size_a = Py_ABS(Py_SIZE(a)), size_b = Py_ABS(Py_SIZE(b));
    PyLongObject *z;
    ...
    /* Ensure a is the larger of the two: */
    ...
    z = _PyLong_New(size_a+1);  
    ...
```

after the addition the result is normalized:

```
 ...
 return long_normalize(z);
```

};

i.e. the possible leading zeros are discarded, but the memory isn't released - 4 bytes aren't worth it, the source of the function can be found [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a10d426bab66a4e1f20d5e1b9aee3dbb435cf309/Objects/longobject.c#L121-L136).

---

Now, we can use @Nathans insight to explain, why the footprint of `(1<<30)+i` is `48.56` and not `44.xy`: The used `py_malloc`-allocator uses memory-blocks with alignment of `8` bytes, that means `36` bytes will be stored in a block of size `40` - the same as the result of `(1<<60)+i` (keep the additional 8-bytes for pointers in mind).

---

To explain the remaining `0.5` bytes we need to dive deeper into details of `py_malloc`-allocator. A good overview is the [source-code itself](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L741), my last try to describe it can be found in this [SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55012694/5769463).

In a nutshell, the allocator manages memory in arenas, each 256MB. When an arena is allocated, the memory is reserved, but not commited. We see memory as "used", only when a so called `pool` is touched. A pool is `4Kb` big ([`POOL_SIZE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L867)) and is used only for memory-blocks with same size - in our case `32` byte. That means the resolution of `peak_used_memory` is 4Kb and cannot be responsible for those `0.5` bytes.

However, these pools must be managed, which leads to an additional overhead: `py_malloc` needs a [`pool_header`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L880-L890) per pool:

```
/* Pool for small blocks. */
struct pool_header {
    union { block *_padding;
            uint count; } ref;          /* number of allocated blocks    */
    block *freeblock;                   /* pool's free list head         */
    struct pool_header *nextpool;       /* next pool of this size class  */
    struct pool_header *prevpool;       /* previous pool       ""        */
    uint arenaindex;                    /* index into arenas of base adr */
    uint szidx;                         /* block size class index        */
    uint nextoffset;                    /* bytes to virgin block         */
    uint maxnextoffset;                 /* largest valid nextoffset      */
};
```

The size of this struct is `48` (called `POOL_OVERHEAD`) bytes on my Linux_64 machine. This `pool_header` is a part of the pool (a quite smart way to avoid additional allocation via cruntime-memory-allocator) and will take place of two `32`-byte-blocks, that means a pool has [place for `126` `32` byte integers](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/8905fcc85a6fc3ac394bc89b0bbf40897e9497a6/Objects/obmalloc.c#L943):

```
/* Return total number of blocks in pool of size index I, as a uint. */
#define NUMBLOCKS(I) ((uint)(POOL_SIZE - POOL_OVERHEAD) / INDEX2SIZE(I))
```

Which leads to:

- `4Kb/126 = 32.51` bytes footprint for `1000+i`, plus additional 8 bytes for the pointer.
- `(30<<1)+i` needs `40` bytes, that means `4Kb` has place for `102` blocks, of  which one (there are remaining `16` bytes when pool is divided in `40`-bytes block, and they can be used for the `pool_header`) is used for`pool_header`, which leads to `4Kb/101=40.55` bytes (plus `8` byte pointer).

We can also see, that there are some additional overhead, responsible for ca. `0.01` byte per integer - not big enough for me to care.

Answer (score 2):

The `int` object only requires 28 bytes, but Python uses 8-byte alignment: memory is allocated in blocks that are multiples of 8 bytes in size. So the actual memory used by each `int` object is 32 bytes. See this excellent article on [Python memory management](https://rushter.com/blog/python-memory-managment/) for more details.

I don't yet have an explanation for the remaining half byte, but I'll update this if I find one.

Comment: Actually a pretty good guess! However the situation is more subtle. See my answer (which explains also 0.5 bytes).