# special Chinese characters comparison

Tags: python, encode, cjk

. There are something misunderstanding when comparing two characters "李","李".

```
>>> "李" == "李"
False

>>> id("李") # fisrt one
140041303457584

>>> id("李") # second one
140041303457584
```

. The first character "李“ id is equal to the second "李" id, but when i try to compare their id to see what happen:

```
>>> id("李") == id("李")
False
```

. However, I tried to use chrome "Ctrl + F" that searching the first "李" and matched the second "李".

. Does anyone know what happens? what should I do to fix this let the first "李" equal to the second "李"?

Comment: Not a Chinese but I can tell you they're *not* equal.

Comment: Comparing or looking at the id doesn’t really mean anything and doesn’t help because reasons. Concentrate on the string itself.

Comment: As stated above, these two character don't seem to be equal.

    >>>'李'.decode('utf-8') gives u'\u674e'.
    >>> '李'.decode('utf-8') gives u'\uf9e1'

Comment: The first one is a Chinese character, but the second one is a Korean character.

Comment: Thanks all guys, @Nasta thanks, but u know why they have the same id but their the same ids are not equal, it's so weird!

Comment: Because they're not the same character!
They just use the same character representation

Comment: @Nasta I'd emphasize that the `id` check is irrelevant.

Comment: @AndrasDeak to be fair I didn't even know about the id method before today ...

Comment: @Nasta then: `id` is a red herring. Some strings are equal but have a different `id`, and different strings can have the same `id` (but not at the same time) due to memory reuse by the interpreter (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython). It's all a cpython implementation detail. One should ignore the `id` and just use `==` when comparing values (one typical exception is `None`-testing with `is None`).

Comment: @AndrasDeak
TIL! 
Cheers

Comment: The reason they match on Chrome browser search, Chrome normalizes those similar character variants before search, for convenience.

Comment: I also encountered the same problem. In my case,  '⼀' == '一' is false and their ids are not the same. Still No Solution!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just a coincidence that two character looks the same.
like:

```
>>> "ᴀ" == "A"
False
>>> "С" == "C"
False
```

Visit [unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html), and you will find that the first character(unicode: 674e) is the normal character of Chinese, the second one(unicode: f9e1) is a special character that happends to look like the same. But they are indeed different characters.

Comment: `False` in 3.6.

Comment: Sorry. It is indeed False. At the first glance, I think this may be the typo of the author, or there are some special characters like tab or space in the string. After testing it. I find the real reason.