# Why are two same strings found to be unequal?

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to search for a string within a list. They look exactly the same but why are they not equal?

```py
l = ['liệu',]
a = bytes(l[0],encoding='utf-8')
print(a)

i = 'liệu'
print(bytes(i,encoding='utf-8'))

print(i==l[0])
```

Current Output:

```
b'li\xc3\xaa\xcc\xa3u'
b'li\xe1\xbb\x87u'
False
```

How do we make it `True`?

Comment: The strings doesn't seem the same.

Comment: they are both 'liệu' aren't they ?

Comment: No they aren't the same utf code. Copy and paste both e's in their own byte form and you will see they are different

Comment: I run your code on my machine using Jupyter Notebook, but yields `True`

Comment: oh that is odd indeed, I am using sublime text. Is there some sort of package that must be installed?

Comment: Is the encoding known?

Comment: After inspecting the website html I conclude that the encoding is utf-8. Please have a look at the website: https://lamerfashion.com/products/l62f18h016-s4400. The relevant string is in the text area under the product picture.

Comment: @LuluVo, If you need to compare them, why dont you take the one it actually works and use that instead? I was able to use `a == a` succesfully. Why use the one that doesnt work?

Comment: @Netwave yes that's one way to do it ^^ . But i am still quite frustrated due to the mysterious nature of this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see with the bytes representation they are both different strings:

```
>>> a = 'liệu'
>>> b = 'liệu'
>>> a == a
True
>>> b == b
True
>>> a == b
False
```

They differ **after** the third letter:

```
>>> for l1, l2 in zip(a, b):
...     print(l1 == l2)
... 
True
True
False
False
```

This doesn't mean that the `u` is different,but for sure the `e` is.

Comment: 'ệ'=='ệ'
False

Comment: do you know why they might be different ?  To my normal eyes, I can discern no difference. I have obtained the list through web scraping, the other string I typed in python to compare with the list.

Comment: @LuluVo, probably the one you scrapped was written in a different encoding.

Comment: In my browser I can see difference. Look on small dot under e, one is exactly in the middle and second is a bit shifter to left side.

Answer (score 1):

Copy paste the `ệ` of the first `"liệu"` in the second `"liệu"` or vice versa. That should make sure both are the exact replicas of each other. That should definitely give you this output:

```
b'li\xe1\xbb\x87u'
b'li\xe1\xbb\x87u'
True
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: @Lulu Vo - The easiest fix to your problem is to simply use the same `ệ` for both `l` and `i` which yields `True` by copy pasting one of the `ệ`  in the other `liệu`.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> 'ệ'=='ệ'
False
```

Why like that? because they are different characters but just look the same, you can check the two characters in the [unicode table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html), u will find they have different Unicode.

I had the same issue like you before, you can visit my [issue page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55488577/special-chinese-characters-comparison)

Comment: how did you resolve the issue ?  I have obtained the string from web scraping so I have to compare my own typed string to it

Comment: one simple way, Even though they are different characters, we could replace one of them into correct one.

Comment: if you have many characters like above your describe, I advise you can create a characters dictionary to map them.