# String comparison in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, compare, string-comparison

My string comparison doesn't work,

Any ideas?

```
a = person.category[0].lower()
b = to_delete[5].lower()

print("test ", repr(a), "type: ", type(a))
print("test ", repr(b), "type: ", type(b))
print(a == b)
print(a is b)
print("éclairage public" == b)
print("éclairage public" == a )
```

returns:

```
test  'éclairage public' type:  <class 'str'>
test  'éclairage public' type:  <class 'str'>
False
False
False
True
```

So "b" doesn't have the expected composition but I don't know why!

Comment: What are the outputs of a simple `print(a)` and `print(b)`?

Comment: Obviously I'd like all to be true!

Comment: @Alex - Try copy pasting one of the `éclairage public` to the other so that both of them are the exact replicas of each other. This way they will have the same number of bytes (byte representation).

Comment: @AdarshChavakula output for a simple print(a) and print(b) is 
`éclairage public`
`éclairage public`

Comment: On Python 3.7, I get True, False, True, True. The False only appears for `a is b` and that is because they have a different `id`. Try `id(a)` or `id(b)` to confirm that.

Comment: @TP7 Thanks but I also wanted `a==b`to be true!

Comment: We can't reproduce the issue if you don't provide the contents of `person.category` and `to_delete`.

Comment: You probably have Unicode normalization issues. Compare the values of `a.encode()` and `b.encode()`

Comment: @amanb You probably tested it with a fake entry like `a="éclairage public"`and `b=éclairage public`, that's why it works. It seem that I have a problem with my `b`value. But how can I see the problem?

Comment: @Alex, not sure what fake entry means? I copied the text exactly as it is from the question.

Comment: Compare the results of `b'e\xcc\x81'.decode()` and `b'\xc3\xa9'.decode()`. Both *look* like `é`, but they are two different Unicode strings.

Comment: @glhr,  @chepner one came from a website, other from a manual entry. Well done, outputs are `a encode =  b'\xc3\xa9clairage public'
b encode =  b'e\xcc\x81clairage public'`

Comment: @Alex - Can you please provide the contents of `person.category` and `to_delete`?

Comment: So how can I encode them in the same type?

Comment: @Alex  - Check this question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860073/why-are-two-same-strings-found-to-be-unequal

Comment: thank you guys! your awsome

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is almost certainly that `a` and `b` are two different Unicode values with the same *normalization*. As a simple example, consider these two ways to display `é`:

```
>>> b'e\xcc\x81'.decode()
'é'
>>> b'\xc3\xa9'.decode()
'é'
```

The first is a two-character string consisting of `e` (U+0065) and the combining diacrtical mark `´` (U+0301). The second is a single character consisting of `é` (U+00E9).

In order to compare them successfully, you need to normalize them. There are several different normalizations available, though which one you use doesn't matter much for comparison purposes as long as you use the *same* one for each.

```
>>> import unicodedata
>>> x = b'e\xcc\x81'.decode()
>>> y = b'\xc3\xa9'.decode()
>>> x == y
False
>>> unicodedata.normalize("NFC", x) == unicodedata.normalize("NFC", y)
True
```

Normalization NFC, for example, normalizes by replacing U+0065/U+0301 with U+00E9. For more information, see https://www.unicode.org/faq/normalization.html. You will probably want to normalize any user input before storing it, and you'll want to make sure that the same normalization is used for all stored data. The FAQ may help you decide which normalization is most appropriate for your use.

Comment: A cleaner way should be to encode/decode strings, but I don't know how to do that. On of the entry comes from web (selenium), the second one comes from the creation of a manual string.

Comment: Encoding/decoding is a separate issue. You need to decode a UTF-8 byte string before you can normalize the result, and you (may) need to encode the normalized result back to UTF-8 for storage.