# why is this comparison between two __dict__s False?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this class:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "amir"
        self.age = 22
```

And I compare two `__dict__`s like this:

```
n1 = Person()
n2 = Person()
print(n1.__dict__.items())   #dict_items([('name', 'amir'), ('age', 22)])
print(n2.__dict__.items())   #dict_items([('name', 'amir'), ('age', 22)])
print(hex(id(n1.__dict__.items())))   #0x7fc83425f310
print(hex(id(n2.__dict__.items())))   #0x7fc83425f310
print(n1.__dict__.items() is n2.__dict__.items())   #False
print(n1.__dict__["name"] is n2.__dict__["name"])   #True
```

Why do I get a `False` result for  `n1.__dict__.items() is n2.__dict__.items()`?

Comment: Are you aware that `is` is the *identity* operator, not the *equality* operator?

Comment: But the definition of identity is that `id` is the same, which it appears to be.

Comment: That the return values of two function calls happen to use the same memory address doesn't imply that you should use anything other than `==` to check equality in Python.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi , i print id for that  :)

Comment: The calls of the `id` happen at different times - notably after the former has gone out of scope. The definition of identity is that `id` is the same *at the same time*.

Comment: assign the items() calls to variables instead and you might see what is going on.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi , how can i get memory address ?

Comment: Why would you want to? You seem to already misunderstand identity, which is even more high level than memory address.

Comment: `n1.__dict__.items() is n2.__dict__.items()` is still at different times, you must assign both to variables and then compare them.

Comment: add the dictionary in your code so that its reproducable

Comment: @MisterMiyagi , for reduce resource consumption

Comment: @thebjorn that is not the issue. The operands live at least as long as the operation. That comparison will always be false, because the two objects compared are not identical.

Comment: @MiladVayani Memory locations are the wrong tool for that job. Memory is an implementation detail - it's usage is dictated by the high level operations, not the other way around. In fact, just inspecting the memory location vie the language itself can affect memory consumption, because it means you are requesting there to be such a location.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877230/why-does-id-id-and-id-id-in-cpython

Answer (score 4):

You are not comparing whether the dictionaries are the same, which obviously they are not: you would not want or expect the `name` of the first `Person` to change when you change this attribute in another `Person` instance.

What's going on is that `items()` returns a *copy* which then goes out of scope. When you call it again, you might or might not get another copy which coincidentally gets created at the same memory address. (Experimentally, I seem to get a different address, perhaps beacuse I made some minor changes to your code, here: https://ideone.com/AoM14r)

You should be able to prove this to yourself easily by ensuring that the first result *doesn't* go out of scope, e.g. by storing it in a variable.

The proper thing to test is whether `n1.__dict__ is n2.__dict__`, which is always `False`.

Individual `dict` members with the same value will *sometimes* refer to the same object, as an optimization by some Python implementations. For example, small integers get allocated once, and then new variables with the same value are simply references to this value. When the variable's value changes, the reference gets changed to point to a different memory location. The same thing seems to be happening with the two identical `name`s.