# What is the difference between None check and var or default syntax in Python?

Tags: python

I noted this syntax listed as a gotchya but with no explanation as to why:

```
def func(x=None):
    #good
    if x == None:
        x = []

    #bad
    x = x or []
```

In what ways can this be a gotchya?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this particular case, it’s bad because an empty list evaluates to false. If you mutate the list, then the results won’t be as expected

```
def func(x=None):
    x = x or []
    x.append('hello')

mylist = []
func(mylist)
print mylist[0] # doesn't work
```

Since you want to check to see if the caller passed `None` or not, you should just say that explicitly and not try to be clever. Objects like `[]`, `()`, `{}`, `0`, and `False` evaluate to false, as can any user-defined object that wants to — checking for falsehood really catches too many false positives.

(Also: Using `is None` instead of `== None` [can be faster and more reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none).)

Answer (score 2):

`x or []` will return an empty list if `bool(x)` is false. `None` is false, but zeros (ints, longs, floats, etc) and empty collections (`[]`, `{}`, `""`, etc) are also false. So this isn't catching `None`, it's catching falsy object - which isn't equivalent to `x == None` and most likely not what you want (empty collections are perfectly valid input for many algorithms).

Oh, and while we're at it: That should be `x is None` - `is` is the semantically correct (and propably faster) choice for testing identity. `==` can be overwritten by x, and you can't be sure if it won't consider `None` equal to itself or even break on it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best idiom to check for any python singleton is:

```
if x is None:
    x = []
```

The reason is that some objects like ORM objects in django or sqlalchemy, for example, are lazy (they will not call the database until the latest possible time). Using the other options to check for None may trigger evaluation of an expensive operation.