# "is" not working in python IDE but working in command line

Tags: python

I couldn't understand why this is happening actually..

Take a look at this python code :

```
    word = raw_input("Enter Word")
    length = len(word)

    if word[length-1:] is "e" :
         print word + "d"
```

If I give input "love", its output must be "loved". So, when I wrote this in PyScripter IDE, its neither showing error nor the output. But I tried the same code in python shell, its working!

I'd like to know why this is happening.

Comment: Have you tried just having the script repeat the input to see what comes in when using the IDE and the shell?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none.  `is` is the wrong operator here -- use `==` instead.

Comment: A couple of things .. 1. Are you *sure* it's working like that anywhere? It shouldn't. `is` is the identity operator and two strings with the same value are not identical, they are equal so you should be using `==`, also 2, Note you can use negative indexes in sequences so, you do not need to know the length of `word` you can just use `word[-1]` to get the last character.

Comment: @tjm: It is perfectly possible that this works due to string interning or similar things.  Strings are immutable, so the interpreter is free to reuse them where appropriate,

Comment: @SvenMarnach. Ah ok. Good to know. I guess I've got a little reading to do myself then. And to the OP, let me rephrase that then, not as it *shouldn't* work, but it is not *guaranteed* to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `is` keyword will only work if the strings have exactly the same identity, which is not guaranteed even if the strings have the same value. You should use `==` instead of `is` here to compare the values of the strings.

Or better still, use [`endswith`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

```
if word.endswith("e"):
     print word + "d"
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `==` in this case instead of `is`. `Is` checks for identity of objects, that is, id('e') would have to be equal with id of the string returned by the slice. As it happens, cpython stores one-letter strings (and small integers) as constants so this often works. But it is not reliable as any other implementation could not use this and then even `"e" is "e"` wouldn't have to yield True. Just use `==` and it should work.

edit: `endswith` mentioned by @MarkByers is even better for this case. safer, more readable and all that