# difference between 'is' and '=='

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any difference between “foo is None” and “foo == None”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none)

Quite a simple question really.

Whats the difference between:

```
if a.b is 'something':
```

and

```
if a.b == 'something':
```

excuse my ignorance

Comment: When you realize a question is simple, it is a sure bet there probably already is an answer on SO..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first checks for *identity* the second for *equality*.

Examples:

The first operation using `is` *may* or *may not* result in `True` based on where these items, i.e., strings, are stored in memory.

```
a='this is a very long string'
b='this is a very long string'

a is b
False
```

Checking, [id()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) shows them stored at different locations.

```
id(a)
62751232

id(b)
62664432
```

The second operation (`==`) will give `True` since the strings are equal.

```
a == b
True
```

Another example showing that `is` can be `True` or `False` (compare with the first example), but `==` works the way we'd expect:

```
'3' is '3'
True
```

this implies that both of these short literals were stored in the same memory location unlike the two longer strings in the example above.

```
'3' == '3'
True
```

No surprise here, what we would have expected.

I believe `is` uses [id()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id) to determine if the same objects in memory are referred to (see @SvenMarnach comment below for more details)

Comment: "I believe is uses id() to determine if the same objects in memory are referred to."  Not exactly -- `is` simply compares the pointers.  In the CPython implementation, `id()` returns the pointer as an integer, so this will be equivalent.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Thanks Sven, I'll update my answer to point to your comment.

Comment: I've only ever used `is` in `if a.b is None` context. Any other example of when you could use it (e.g. would you use it to compare object instances?)

Comment: Sorry I got my answer from the duplicate  :)

Answer (score 3):

`a is b` is true if `a` and `b` are *the same object*. They can compare equal, but be different objects, eg:

```
>>> a = [1, 2]
>>> b = [1, 2]
>>> c = b
>>> a is b
False
>>> a is c
False
>>> b is c
True
>>> a == b == c
True
```