# Difference between 'not x' and 'x==None' in python

Tags: python

Can `not x` and `x==None` give different answers if `x` is a class instance ?

I mean how is `not x` evaluated if `x` is a class instance ?

Comment: Does your class have a `__nonzero__` method (or `__bool__` in 3.x)?

Comment: It will if `x = False`, at least.

Comment: [Yes.](http://ideone.com/t9yWj8)

Comment: Keep in mind that if you're going to compare against `None`, you should do it `x is None`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

yes it **can** give different answers.

```
x == None
```

will call the [`__eq__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) method to valuate the operator and give the result implemented compared to the `None` singleton.

```
not x
```

will call the [`__nonzero__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__nonzero__) ([`__bool__()`](http://docs.python.org/3.1/reference/datamodel.html#object.__bool__) in python3) method to valuate the operator. The interpreter will convert `x` to a boolean (`bool(x)`) using the mentioned method and then inverse its returned value because of the [`not` operator](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not).

```
x is None
```

means that the reference x points to the `None` object, which is a singleton of type `NoneType` and will valuate false in comparaisons. The [`is` operator](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.is_) tests object identity, and thus whether or not the two objects compared are the *same* instance of an object, and not *similar* objects.

Comment: Note that you should not use `x == None`, and should instead use `x is None`

Comment: @Cthulhu `x == None` and `x is None` should never result in different answers. But, since `None` is a singleton instance, it is considered better practice to use `is None`.

Comment: @arshajii `x == None` and `x is None` could return different answers if an implemented object's `__eq__` returns True (for some reason), but the object itself is not `None`.

Comment: @Cthulhu Yes, if `x` is an instance of an awful class that defines `__eq__` badly. But arshajii's reason is better.

Comment: Yes, *should never* is different than *can never* I suppose.

Answer (score 5):

```
class A():
    def __eq__(self, other):  #other receives the value None
        print 'inside eq'
        return True
    def __nonzero__(self):    
        print 'inside nonzero'
        return True
...     
>>> x = A()
>>> x == None      #calls __eq__
inside eq
True
>>> not x          #calls __nonzero__
inside nonzero
False
```

`not x` is eqivalent to:

```
not bool(x)
```

Py 3.x:

```
>>> class A(object):
        def __eq__(self, other):    #other receives the value None
                print ('inside eq')
                return True
        def __bool__(self):    
                print ('inside bool')
                return True
...     
>>> x = A()
>>> x == None       #calls __eq__
inside eq
True
>>> not x           #calls __bool__ 
inside bool 
False
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes; [`not` uses `__bool__`](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not) (in Python 3; Python 2 uses `__nonzero__`), and `x == None` can be overridden by `__eq__`.

[(Both are shown here.)](http://ideone.com/t9yWj8)

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is *positive* the `not` of it means *negative* and vice-versa.

`x == None` means it will only be `True` if `x is None` is `True` else False. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26595/1309352).

By positive I mean the `if` block is chosen. `True` is also positive.

Answer (score -1):

`not x` is true for a wide variety of values, e.g. *0*, *None*, *""*, *False*, *[]*, *{}*, etc.

`x == None` is only true for the one specific value *None*.

If **x** is a class instance, then both `not x` and `x == None` will be false, but that doesn't mean that those are equivalent expressions.

---

Fine; that previous paragraph should read:

If **x** is a class instance, then both `not x` and `x == None` will be false unless someone is playing silly buggers with the class definition.

Comment: `If x is a class instance, then both not x and x == None will be false, but that doesn't mean that those are equivalent expressions.` - That is not true at all, class instance can evaluate to both `False` and `None`.

Comment: When will a class instance evaluate to `None` apart from explicitly assigning `None` to it? You mean, when `__eq__ ()` returns `None`?

Comment: Your answer started out well.

Comment: OK, I see from Ashwini's answer above that it is possible to craft a class definition for which "*not x*" is true and "*x == None*" is true, but I don't see how that it serves any useful purpose other than to prove that it's possible.

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it, I can imagine lots of cases where a class object can be considered to be "zero"; e.g. a numeric class like complex numbers or quaternions.