# Loop Function like to Arduino in Python

Tags: python, arduino, raspberry-pi

I am new at programming and I had some knowledge of Arduino C coding, however, I wanted to move over to more complex coding for Raspberry Pi in Python. I like how in Arduino you can just enter loop(), however, I cannot find anything similar in Python. I am coding a program that repeatedly checks the time, and when the time hits a certain point, it starts another function in the code. The "while True:" loop does not seem to work. Please disregard the formatting in the coding. When I copied it the formatting was screwed up. The coding is a basic idea of my main program. When it hits the time, I need it to print something.

```
    while True:
        import datetime
        if datetime.time is (12, 15, 17, 000000):
           print "TEST"
           break
```

Comment: Don't use `is`, use `==`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your while loop looks correct to me. The problem (I believe) is that you don't quite understand how to get the current time, and compare it the time you are interested in.

`datetime.time` doesn't default to the current time, it is actually the structure that contains a time. It could be any time, 1:00:01 AM, 1:13:00 PM (now), etc.

If you want to get the current time, you would use `datetime.datetime.now().time()`. What this does, is ask the `datetime` class "Hey, what is the current date and time?", and returns a `datetime` object containing that data. Since you are just interested in the current time, adding `.time()` will return a `time` object that just contains the current time. This should replace the `datetime.time` in your code.

As for what you are actually comparing to (the `(12, 15, 17, 000000)`), you actually need to tell python that you are using a `time` object by using `datetime.time(12, 15, 17, 000000)` instead.

Also, as mentioned you should use `==` when testing for equality. The `is` keyword tells you if two variables point to the same object, not if two different objects are equal. Unless you're sure you should use `is`, you should probably use `==` instead.

Overall, I believe this should work:

```
import datetime

while True:
    if datetime.datetime.now().time() == datetime.time(12, 15, 17, 000000):
       print "TEST"
       break
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#time-objects) for the documentation on the `datetime` library.

EDIT: Since I don't have enough reputation to comment on your question here's how you would get your program to work for a specific date:

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime), you construct a `datetime` object using `datetime.datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond]]]])` with each additional set of brackets being optional.

So the only things we would have to change from the code above is to use a `datetime` object instead of a `time` object, which means we just need to get rid of the `.time()` part, and use the `datetime.datetime()` constructor instead of the `datetime.time()` constructor.

```
import datetime

while True:
    my_date = datetime.datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
    if datetime.datetime.now() == my_date:
       print "TEST"
       break
```

Comment: You code would not even run, what is  `datetime.time.now().time()`?

Comment: Whoops accidentally wrote that instead of `datetime.datetime.now().time()`. Thanks for catching that.