# how python "is" decide if two objects are the same?

Tags: python, object

in python, x is y return ture when x and y are the same object

```
>>> a = "5"
>>> b = "5"
>>>
>>> a is b
True
>>>
>>> c = a + b
>>> c
'55'
>>> d = b + a
>>> d
'55'
>>>
>>> c is d
False
>>>
```

To what I understand, a and b are two different objects, but why a is b return True and c is d return False?

Even we regard both a and b as string objects with the same content to explain why a is b return true, why c is d return false  then?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python    
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none

Comment: `a` and `b` are **not** guaranteed to be different objects, because the Python interpreter can, at its option, choose to intern immutable values when read.

Comment: Please stop upvoting duplicates.

Comment: I think this is because the interpreter is just string pooling, is this wrong?

Comment: a and b are actually just names referring to the same integer object `5`, what you can also check with `hex(id(a))` and `hex(id(b))`

Comment: @Cipher They are both names referring to the same *string* object, but only because the implementation is interning the string object `"5"`.

Comment: @chepner sorry didn't see the `"` >.<