# How to correctly use 'is' in python

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to python. And I have a question.

```
 def set_man(self, new_pos):
    if new_pos is 'left' or 'right' or 'boat':
        self.man = new_pos
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

will this work? Or do i need to call if new_pos for each or?

Comment: No.  Try `if new_pos in ('left','right','boat'):`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That was pretty quick!

Comment: That won't work for two reasons.  One will be displayed by people with better dupe skills than I.  The other is that `is` tests to see if one object is the same object as another.  That is, it gives `True` only if they have the same place in memory.  What you want, though, is to see if they are equivalent.  Do `if new_pos in ("left", "right", "boat"):`

Comment: Yeah, so i know. That is basicly the same as using == to check two strings in java?

Comment: The first reason that I mentioned is demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values) post.

Comment: This is a double dupe and I accidentally retracted... :) [dupe1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132988/is-there-a-difference-between-and-is-in-python) [dupe2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-do-i-test-one-variable-against-multiple-values)

Comment: "That is basicly the same as using == to check two strings in java" No it's not. Was that your question? It doesn't look like that.

Comment: @timgeb it's actually more a dupe of the dupe2 link you provided, as his question really is about checking one value against several others. I just voted to close it as dupe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will this work?

no it won't, because what you wrote is actually:

- `new_pos is "left"` → `id(new_pos) == id("left")` → boolean value `X`
- `'right'` alone → `bool('right')` → always `True`
- `'boat'` alone → `bool('boat')` → always `True`

when you evaluate that expression you get: `X or True or True` which always evaluates to `True`. So as a result, whatever `new_pos` is your function will *always* return True and assign `new_pos` to `self.man`.

> Or do i need to call if new_pos for each or?

well that's a way to do it:

```
if new_pos is 'left' or new_pos is 'right' or new_pos is 'boat':
```

but that's a bit verbose, and not very elegant. A better way to write it down is to ask whether `new_pos` is in the tuple `('left', 'right', 'boat')`:

```
if new_pos in ('left', 'right', 'boat'):
```

*Nota Bene:* even though I prefer to use `is` when working with strings (as it often makes beautiful sentences like `if user_input is "yes"`, be aware that this is an exceptional behaviour of the `is` operator.

The `is` operator is being used to match whether two instances are the same instance (i.e. the same object in memory), whereas the `==` operator checks whether the *value* of both instances are the same, and the `==` operator can be defined by the developer using `__eq__` for custom behaviours.

This is why the `is` operator is called the 'identity' operator, whereas the `==` operator is the `equality` operator. Given that the `id()` operator gives an unique id for an instance: you can translate `a is b` into `id(a) == id(b)`. Have a read of [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988017/string-comparison-in-python-is-vs?lq=1) for more on that.

Comment: I don't think adding `is not None` to the `right` and `boat` checks is appropriate. Empty strings and containers and the zero values of various numeric types are also "falsey" in Python, not only `None`. Maybe use `bool('left')` instead of `'left' is not None`?

Comment: oh, what I wrote was just the meaning in full english, not in python. Which is why I used the backticks! But you're right, let me detail more what is really being done.

Comment: edited, hope you'll like it better that way ☺

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn the topic, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595/is-there-any-difference-between-foo-is-none-and-foo-none)

If you just want your code to work as it is, use it like that:

```
 def set_man(self, new_pos):
    if new_pos is 'left' or new_pos is 'right' or new_pos is 'boat':
        self.man = new_pos
        return True
    else:
        return False
```